# Flatten command: matrix as second argument

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, programming, syntax

One thing I could never wrap my head around is how `Flatten` works when provided with a matrix as the second argument, and the *Mathematica* help isn't particularly good on this one.

Taken from the [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html) *Mathematica* documentation:

```
Flatten[list, {{s11, s12, ...}, {s21, s22, ...}, ...}]
```

> Flattens `list` by combining all levels $s_{ij}$ to make each level $i$ in the result.

Could someone elaborate on what this actually means/does?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

One convenient way to think of `Flatten` with the second argument is that it performs something like `Transpose` for ragged (irregular) lists. Here is a simple example:

```
In[63]:=  Flatten[{{1,2,3},{4,5},{6,7},{8,9,10}},{{2},{1}}]
Out[63]= {{1,4,6,8},{2,5,7,9},{3,10}}
```

What happens is that elements which constituted level `1` in the original list are now constituents at level `2` in the result, and vice versa. This is exactly what `Transpose` does, but done for irregular lists. Note however, that some information about positions is lost here, so we can not directly inverse the operation:

```
In[65]:= Flatten[{{1,4,6,8},{2,5,7,9},{3,10}},{{2},{1}}]
Out[65]= {{1,2,3},{4,5,10},{6,7},{8,9}}
```

To have it reversed correctly, we'd have to do something like this:

```
In[67]:= Flatten/@Flatten[{{1,4,6,8},{2,5,7,9},{3,{},{},10}},{{2},{1}}]
Out[67]= {{1,2,3},{4,5},{6,7},{8,9,10}}
```

A more interesting example is when we have deeper nesting:

```
In[68]:= Flatten[{{{1,2,3},{4,5}},{{6,7},{8,9,10}}},{{2},{1},{3}}]
Out[68]= {{{1,2,3},{6,7}},{{4,5},{8,9,10}}}
```

Here again, we can see that `Flatten` effectively worked like (generalized) `Transpose`, interchanging pieces at the first 2 levels. The following will be harder to understand:

```
In[69]:=  Flatten[{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{6, 7}, {8, 9,  10}}}, {{3}, {1}, {2}}]
Out[69]= {{{1, 4}, {6, 8}}, {{2, 5}, {7, 9}}, {{3}, {10}}}
```

The following image illustrates this generalized transpose:

[image: Illustration of cyclic generalized transpose]

We may do it in two consecutive steps:

```
In[72]:=  step1 = Flatten[{{{1,2,3},{4,5}},{{6,7},{8,9,10}}},{{1},{3},{2}}]
Out[72]= {{{1,4},{2,5},{3}},{{6,8},{7,9},{10}}}

In[73]:= step2 =  Flatten[step1,{{2},{1},{3}}]
Out[73]= {{{1,4},{6,8}},{{2,5},{7,9}},{{3},{10}}}
```

Since the permutation `{3,1,2}` can be obtained as `{1,3,2}` followed by `{2,1,3}`. Another way to see how it works is to use numbers which indicate the position in the list structure:

```
Flatten[{{{111, 112, 113}, {121, 122}}, {{211, 212}, {221, 222, 223}}}, {{3}, {1}, {2}}]
(*
==> {{{111, 121}, {211, 221}}, {{112, 122}, {212, 222}}, {{113}, {223}}}
*)
```

From this, one can see that in the outermost list (first level), the third index (corresponding the third level of the original list) grows, in each member list (second level) the first element grows per element (corresponding to the first level of the original list), and finally in the innermost (third level) lists, the second index grows, corresponding to the second level in the original list. Generally, if the k-th element of the list passed as second element is `{n}`, growing the k-th index in the resulting list structure corresponds to increasing the n-th index in the original structure.

Finally, one can combine several levels to effectively flatten the sub-levels, like so:

```
In[74]:=  Flatten[{{{1,2,3},{4,5}},{{6,7},{8,9,10}}},{{2},{1,3}}]
Out[74]= {{1,2,3,6,7},{4,5,8,9,10}}
```

Comment: I think it's easier to understand if the numbers indicate the original position in the nested list. For example, in the three-number permutation example, it would be `Flatten[{{{111, 112, 113}, {121, 122}}, {{211, 212}, {{221,222,223}}}, {{3},{1},{2}}}` and the result would read `{{{111, 121}, {211, 221}}, {{112, 122}, {212, 222}}, {{113}, {223}}}`.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks, but I am not convinced. For me personally, it is easier to track visually distinct numbers and see where they end up in the new structure. But feel free to add this to my answer, this is perfectly fine with me.

Comment: I guess our ways of understanding are just different in that respect. Actually only after rewriting my way, I completely understood the cyclic permutation (but then directly, without the two-step decomposition you did afterward). The point is that this way, you can see immediately which index changes if you move along each list, and you can determine where the number originated in the list structure from without even looking at the original list. In other words, it more directly (at least to me) reveals the *structure* of the transformation.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, I understood your reasoning. But for me, it was easier to understand which elements jumped which lists, rather than look at elements' indices. May be it's just me, I always gravitated to geometry rather than algebra. I think both ways have their merits.

Comment: OK, I've now inserted the example using index-numbers with corresponding explanation.

Comment: Hmmm ... maybe then an image would make it easier to understand (basically draw the original and final list structure with boxes, and use arrows to show where the elements go).

Comment: @celtschk  Perhaps, but it may be hard to do for levels deeper than 2, also because the (sub)lists themselves change. Some kind of diagrams similar to those commonly used to visualize permutations, may indeed be useful. Thanks for your addition, b.t.w.

Comment: I've now drawn an image of the transformation and added it. I think it indeed helps in understanding the transformation.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks, this is really useful! It is now quite clear what is going on, by looking at it. I should've done that.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin For `In[63]:=  Flatten[{{1,2,3},{4,5},{6,7},{8,9,10}},{{2},{1}}]
Out[63]= {{1,4,6,8},{2,5,7,9},{3,10}}`,you say What happens is that elements which constituted level 1 in the original list are now constituents at level 2 in the result. I don't  quite understand, input and output have the same level structure, elements are still in the same level.Could you explain this at large?

Answer (score 89):

A second list argument to `Flatten` serves two purposes.  First, it specifies the order in which indices will be iterated when gathering elements.  Second, it describes list flattening in the final result.  Let's look at each of these capabilities in turn.

**Iteration Order**

Consider the following matrix:

```
$m = Array[Subscript[m, Row[{##}]]&, {4, 3, 2}];
$m // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix result]

We can use a `Table` expression to create a copy of the matrix by iterating over all of its elements:

```
$m === Table[$m[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 2}]
(* True *)
```

This identity operation is uninteresting, but we can transform the array by swapping the order of the iteration variables.  For example, we can swap `i` and `j` iterators.  This amounts to swapping the level 1 and level 2 indices and their corresponding elements:

```
$r = Table[$m[[i, j, k]], {j, 1, 3}, {i, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 2}];
$r // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix result]

If we look carefully, we can see that each original element `$m[[i, j, k]]` will be found to correspond to the resulting element `$r[[j, i, k]]` -- the first two indices have been "swapped".

`Flatten` allows us to express an equivalent operation to this `Table` expression more succintly:

```
$r === Flatten[$m, {{2}, {1}, {3}}]
(* True *)
```

The second argument of the `Flatten` expression explicitly specifies the desired index order: indices 1, 2, 3 are altered to become indices 2, 1, 3.  Note how we did not need to specify a range for each dimension of the array -- a significant notational convenience.

The following `Flatten` is an identity operation since it specifies no change to index order:

```
$m === Flatten[$m, {{1}, {2}, {3}}]
(* True *)
```

Whereas the following expression re-arranges all three indices: 1, 2, 3 -> 3, 2, 1

```
Flatten[$m, {{3}, {2}, {1}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix result]

Again, we can verify that an original element found at the index `[[i, j, k]]` will now be found at `[[k, j, i]]` in the result.

If any indices are omitted from a `Flatten` expression, they are treated as if they had been specified last and in their natural order:

```
Flatten[$m, {{3}}] === Flatten[$m, {{3}, {1}, {2}}]
(* True *)
```

This last example can be abbreviated even further:

```
Flatten[$m, {3}] === Flatten[$m, {{3}}]
(* True *)
```

An empty index list results in the identity operation:

```
$m === Flatten[$m, {}] === Flatten[$m, {1}] === Flatten[$m, {{1}, {2}, {3}}]
(* True *)
```

That takes care of iteration order and index swapping.  Now, let's look at...

**List Flattening**

One might wonder why we had to specify each index in a sublist in the previous examples.  The reason is that each sublist in the index specification specifies which indices are to be flattened together in the result.  Consider again the following identity operation:

```
Flatten[$m, {{1}, {2}, {3}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix result]

What happens if we combine the first two indices into the same sublist?

```
Flatten[$m, {{1, 2}, {3}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix result]

We can see that the original result was a 4 x 3 grid of pairs, but the second result is a simple list of pairs.  The deepest structure, the pairs, were left untouched.  The first two levels have been flattened into a single level.  The pairs in the third level of the source matrix remained unflattened.

We could combine the second two indices instead:

```
Flatten[$m, {{1}, {2, 3}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix result]

This result has the same number of rows as the original matrix, meaning that the first level was left untouched.  But each result row has a flat list of six elements taken from the corresponding original row of three pairs.  Thus, the lower two levels have been flattened.

We can also combine all three indices to get a completely flattened result:

```
Flatten[$m, {{1, 2, 3}}]
```

[image: matrix result]

This can be abbreviated:

```
Flatten[$m, {{1, 2, 3}}] === Flatten[$m, {1, 2, 3}] === Flatten[$m]
(* True *)
```

`Flatten` also offers a shorthand notation when no index swapping is to take place:

```
$n = Array[n[##]&, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}];

Flatten[$n, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}] === Flatten[$n, 0]
(* True *)

Flatten[$n, {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}] === Flatten[$n, 1]
(* True *)

Flatten[$n, {{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5}}] === Flatten[$n, 2]
(* True *)

Flatten[$n, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5}}] === Flatten[$n, 3]
(* True *)
```

**"Ragged" Arrays**

All of the examples so far have used matrices of various dimensions.  `Flatten` offers a very powerful feature that makes it more than just an abbreviation for a `Table` expression.  `Flatten` will gracefully handle the case where sublists at any given level have differing lengths.  Missing elements will be quietly ignored.  For example, a triangular array can be flipped:

```
$t = Array[# Range[#]&, {5}];
$t // TableForm
(*
1               
2   4           
3   6   9       
4   8   12  16  
5   10  15  20  25
*)

Flatten[$t, {{2}, {1}}] // TableForm
(*
1   2   3   4   5
4   6   8   10  
9   12  15      
16  20          
25              
*)
```

... or flipped and flattened:

```
Flatten[$t, {{2, 1}}]
(* {1,2,3,4,5,4,6,8,10,9,12,15,16,20,25} *)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic and thorough explanation!

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks.  I figure that if `Flatten` were generalized to accept a function to apply when flattening (contracting) indices, that would be an excellent start to "tensor algebra in a can".

Comment: 1+ Amazing explanation. The second argument of this function has always bothered me. Now you cleared my understanding.

Comment: Sometimes we need to do internal contractions. Now I know I can do it using `Flatten[$m, {{1}, {2, 3}}]` instead of Map Flatten over some level. It would be nice if `Flatten` accepted negative arguments to do that. So this case could be write like `Flatten[$m, -2]`.

Comment: Great contribution

Comment: Why this excellent answer got less votes than Leonid's :(.

Comment: Dear WReach, Could you tell me that why `the name of varible` has a `prefix symbol` `$`?

Comment: @Tangshutao See the second FAQ on my [profile](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach).

Comment: @WReach, Prefect answer to Flatten, and I have read it carefully. and I can understand this problem with the help of your detailed explalation:-)

Comment: @WReach,Today, I finally understand this advanced usage about `Flatten` with the help of reading your `prefect tutorial` four times. Thanks sincerely!! :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for this fantastic explanation!

Comment: Thanks for so brilliant explanation!!!

Comment: @WReach perfacto, Thanks for such formative answer, only one query, as in your example `$m = Array[Subscript[m, Row[{##}]]&, {4, 3, 2}];
$m // MatrixForm`. If we just want to remove the inner brace(), what should we do? Same matrix just without the inner braces

Comment: @L.K.  if i understand correctly: `Flatten[$m, {{1, 3}, {2}}]`

Comment: Great explanation. 
Nevertheless, `Transpose` or `Reverse` may still be required to get all elements in the right place. 
For example `Transpose[ Flatten[$m, {{1,3},{2}}] ] // MatrixForm`.

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe `Flatten` cannot perform generalized reversals, but `Transpose[Flatten[$m, {{1,3},{2}}]] === Flatten[$m, {{2},{1,3}}]`

Answer (score 14):

I learned a lot from WReach's and Leonid's answers and I'd like to make a small contribution:

It seems worth emphasizing that the primary intention of the list-valued second argument of `Flatten` is merely to flatten certain levels of lists (as WReach mentions in his **List Flattening** section). Using `Flatten` as a ragged `Transpose` seems like a side-effect of this primary design, in my opinion.

For example, yesterday I needed to transform this list

```
lists = {
   {{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 0}, {2, 4}}, {{3, 0}}},
   {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, Sqrt[2]}}, {{3, 4}}} 
   (*, more lists... *)
   };
```

[image: treeform1]

into this one:

```
list2 = {
  {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 4}, {3, 0}},
  {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, Sqrt[2]}, {3, 4}}
  (*, more lists... *)
  }
```

[image: treeform2]

That is, I needed to crush the 2nd and 3rd list-levels together.

I did it with

```
list2 = Flatten[lists, {{1}, {2, 3}}];
```

Answer (score 12):

This is a old question, but frequently asked by a **lot** of people. Today when I was trying to explain how this works, I came across a quite clear explanation, so I think sharing it here would be helpful for further audience.

### What do index means?

First let's make clear what **index** is: In Mathematica every expression is a tree, for example, let's look at a list:

```
TreeForm@{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

[image: illus1]

How you navigate in a tree?

Simple! You start from the root and at each crossing choose which way to go, for example, here if you want to reach `2`, you begin with choosing the **first** path, then choose the **second** path. Let's write it out as `{1,2}` which is the just the index of element `2` in this expression.

### How to understand `Flatten`?

Here consider a simple question, if I don't provide you with a complete expression, but instead I give you all the elements and their indexes, how you construct the original expression? For example, here I give you:

```
{<|"index" -> {1, 1}, "value" -> 1|>, <|"index" -> {1, 2}, "value" -> 2|>, <|"index" -> {2, 1}, "value" -> 3|>, <|"index" -> {2, 2}, "value" -> 4|>}
```

and tell you all heads are `List`, so what's the original expression?

Well, surely you can reconstruct the original expression as `{{1,2},{3,4}}`, but how? You probably can list the following steps:

1. First we look at the first element of index and sort and gather by it. Then we know that the **first** element of the whole expression should contain the **first two** elements in the original list...
2. Then we continue to look at the second argument, do the same...
3. Finally we get the original list as `{{1,2},{3,4}}`.

Well, that's reasonable! So what if I tell you, no, you should first sort and gather by the second element of the index and then gather by the first element of the index? Or I say we don't gather them twice, we just sort by both elements but give the first argument higher priority?

Well, you would probably get the following two list respectively, right?

1. `{{1,3},{2,4}}`
2. `{1,2,3,4}`

Well, check by yourself, `Flatten[{{1,2},{3,4}},{{2},{1}}]` and `Flatten[{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2}}]` do the same!

So, how you understand the second argument of Flatten?

1. Each list element inside the main list, for example, `{1,2}`, means you should **GATHER** all the lists according to these elements in the index, in other words these **levels**.
2. The order inside a list element represents how you **SORT** the elements gathered inside a list in previous step. for example, `{2,1}` means the position at the second level has higher priority than the position at the first level.

### Examples

Now let's have some practice to be familiar with previous rules.

#### 1. `Transpose`

The goal of `Transpose` on a simple m*n matrix is to make $A_{i,j} \rightarrow A^T_{j,i}$. But we can consider it another way, originally we sort the element by their `i` index first then sort them by their `j` index, now all we need to do is to change to sort them by `j` index first then by `i` next! So the code becomes:

```
Flatten[mat,{{2},{1}}]
```

Simple, right?

#### 2. Traditional `Flatten`

The goal of traditional flatten on a simple m*n matrix is to create a 1D array instead of a 2D matrix, for example: `Flatten[{{1,2},{3,4}}]` returns `{1,2,3,4}`. This means that we don't **gather** elements this time, we only **sort** them, first by their first index then by the second:

```
Flatten[mat,{{1,2}}]
```

#### 3. `ArrayFlatten`

Let's discuss a most simple case of ArrayFlatten, here we have a 4D list:

```
{{{{1,2},{5,6}},{{3,4},{7,8}}},{{{9,10},{13,14}},{{11,12},{15,16}}}}
```

so how we can do such a conversion to make it a 2D list?

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 5 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 7 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 9 & 10 \\
 13 & 14 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 11 & 12 \\
 15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right) \rightarrow \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Well, this is simple too, we need the group by the original first and the third level index first, and we should give the first index higher priority in sorting. The same goes to the second and the forth level:

```
Flatten[mat,{{1,3},{2,4}}]
```

#### 4. "Resize" a image

Now we have a image, for example:

```
img=Image@RandomReal[1,{10,10}]
```

But it's definitely too small for us to view, so we want to make it bigger by extending each pixel to a 10*10 size huge pixel.

First we shall try:

```
ConstantArray[ImageData@img,{10,10}]
```

But it returns a 4D matrix with dimensions {10,10,10,10}. So we should `Flatten` it. This time we want the third argument to takes higher priority instead of the first one, so a minor tuning would work:

```
Image@Flatten[ConstantArray[ImageData@img,{10,10}],{{3,1},{4,2}}]
```

A comparison:

[image: illus2]

Hope this could help!

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer I've seen on how this works. Even more succintly, if you have a `mat` whose elements are indexed by `mat[i, j, k, l]` then `Flatten[mat,{{1,3},{2,4}}]` first groups/gathers the elements based on `(i, k)` (ordered by `i` then `k`) and then within each group further groups the elements by `(j, l)` (ordered by `j` then `l`).

Comment: In the concrete array you gave for your `ArrayFlatten` example, the elements with value 1 through 4 share the same (i, k) indexes in the original list (namely 1, 1). If we just left at at this (i.e. did `Flatten[mat, {{1, 3}}]`) then each of the 4 elements at level 1 correspond to different combinations of `(i, k)`. By default Flatten will leave the other dimensions untouched, so level 2 will still correspond to `j` and level 3 will correspond to `l`. 

To get just a 2D array, we then apply the second group by on `(j, l)`.