# Equating matrices (or higher order tensors) element-wise

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

Say I have two matrices (or, as in my case, higher order tensors) $A,B$, and I want to solve the equation $A=B$. To do so , I need a list of equations that equate entry-wise the elements of $A$ and $B$ (then I can pass this list to `Solve` or `DSolve` or whatnot). Is there a simpler way to get this list than

`Thread /@ Thread[A == B] // Flatten`

Because this only works for matrices and I need to add another `Thread` for each rank. I'm sure some of you code-golfers will come up with somehting elegant and unreadable...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about flattening first?

```
Thread[Flatten /@ (A==B)]
```

Comment: this evaluates `A==B`, then maps `Flatten` over the result; is this what you intended? (compare `Thread[Flatten /@ (a \[Equal] b)] // Trace` to the trace of the code I give in my answer to see what I mean)

Comment: Yes, to be consistent with what he was doing for matrices

Comment: Right, I see. He has in mind a symbolic matrix on the left hand side, because this does not work for both numerical (also this is what it seems from his motivation).

Comment: Yeah. RM's second solution is the only "bullet-proof" one so far. Your solution doesn't work for arbitrary dimensional tensors unless you manually change the `2`

Comment: Great. How did I not try this first?

Comment: Yes, I could change 2 to `Length@Dimensions[c]` to fix that, but there must be a better way

Answer (score 10):

The following method is broken for packed arrays.  It works for many functions besides `Equal`, but some functions such as Equal, Unequal, and SameQ behave unexpectedly with regard to the `Listable` attribute and packed arrays.  I am exploring this further.  A far less clean but valid substitute is:

```
Block[{$},
  SetAttributes[$, Listable];
  A ~$~ B /. $ -> Equal
]
```

---

Another option is to use `Listable` itself:

```
{A, B} = RandomInteger[3, {2, 4, 3, 2}];

Block[{Equal},
 SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];
 A == B
]
```

> {{{False, True}, {False, True}, {False, False}}, {{False,     True},
>   {False, False}, {False, False}}, {{False, False}, {False,     True},
>   {False, False}}, {{False, False}, {False, False}, {False,     True}}}

Somewhat more efficient is to use the undocumented function `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` which behaves as though one did `SetAttributes[Equal, Listable]` directly, saving an extra step of evaluation that occurs with the method above.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Equal},
  SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];
  A == B
]
```

Comment: I always liked those Block solutions. +1

Comment: I never think of block — Is there a reason to choose/performance difference between changing (temporarily) `Equal` to have the `Listable` attribute and defining a function that is `Listable` and does the same like in mine?

Comment: @R.M A simple test shows that (for some cases at least) my method is more efficient.  `MapThread` is slightly ahead but also less automatic in a way.  I think that using InheritedBlock is arguably the cleanest method, because it directly sets the Listable attribute on the active function.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks :)

Comment: Mr.Wizard, I would also think that your `InheritedBlock` solution should be the most efficient, elegant, robust, and general solution of all so far. The `MapThread` one only works for matrices. However, there's a behaviour I'm not understanding... Got a min?

Comment: @Rojo I believe this works for all element types.  `Listable` supersedes other rules.  Please check the behavior again and tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yeah... Seems like `Equal` doesn't respect `Listable` with packed arrays... Check it out

Comment: @Rojo I am in chat now.

Comment: I don't understand you statement about ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` saving an extra step of evaluation. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @rcollyer, well, in the cases where these methods *do* work doing `Block[{f}, f /@ stuff]` with an external definition of `f` replaces the local definition of `f` with the global one after the `Block` evaluates.  Using `InheritedBlock` the *function* is cloned and operates directly on its arguments without an intermediate form.

Comment: And, no this wasn't an idle question. Their difference has always confused me. But, I think I'm starting to see their differences. With `f[x_]:=x^2` for concreteness, `Block[{f}, f /@ {a,b}]` is `{f[a], f[b]}` until `Block` returns, then as `f` wasn't redefined in the `Block`, it is evaluated. However, `InheritedBlock[{f}, f /@ {a,b}]` is `{a^2, b^2}` before `InheritedBlock` returns if `f` isn't redefined as it has been cloned.

Comment: It is almost like both types of blocks set up their own contexts, and `InheritedBlock` promotes the existing definitions of its arguments into the context while `Block` does not.

Answer (score 10):

My personal favourite for this type of task is [`LogicalExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LogicalExpand.html) (and I can't believe that hasn't been mentioned in the existing 5 answers...)

```
In[1]:= A = Array[a, {2, 2}];
        B = Array[b, {2, 2}];
        LogicalExpand[A == B]

Out[3]= b[1, 1] == a[1, 1] && b[1, 2] == a[1, 2] && 
        b[2, 1] == a[2, 1] && b[2, 2] == a[2, 2]
```

This will also work just as simply in the case of the higher-rank tensors that you're interested in.

If you want the output as a list, then you could do a `Block` hack like:

```
In[4]:= Block[{And = List}, LogicalExpand[A == B]]

Out[4]= {b[1, 1] == a[1, 1], b[1, 2] == a[1, 2], 
         b[2, 1] == a[2, 1], b[2, 2] == a[2, 2]}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `A == B` evaluates, at least not without other methods.  But, since this probably doesn't matter for the question at hand, +1.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe I'm missing something, but `Solve` will work with any depth of tensor. For example,

```
A = Table[a[i,j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
B = Table[b[i,j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];

Solve[ A == B, Flatten @ A ]
```

> ```
> {{a[1, 1] -> b[1, 1], a[1, 2] -> b[1, 2], 
>    a[2, 1] -> b[2, 1], a[2, 2] -> b[2, 2]}}
> ```

The tricky part is usually to extract the variables from the matrices. Since $A$ is completely specified, then `Flatten @ A` here works.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it that has not been proposed yet is:

```
Equal @@@ Transpose[Flatten /@ {mat1, mat2}]
```

This should work regardless of whether it is numeric or symbolic or what the order of the tensor is.

---

An answer that I had earlier was to exploit the `Listable` attribute of `Times` and then replace with `Equal` (only for symbolic matrices/tensors) as:

```
mat1 mat2 /. Times -> Equal // Flatten
```

However, as [Rojo pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/equating-matrices-or-higher-order-tensors-element-wise#comment8636_3220), if the symbolic expressions themselves have `Times` inside them, the above won't work. The way around is to use [his suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/equating-matrices-or-higher-order-tensors-element-wise#comment8641_3220) and create function that has the `Listable` attribute and does the job:

```
Flatten@Function[{a, b}, a == b, Listable][mat1, mat2]
```

Comment: Now your first one is cuute but daangerous. What if your matrixes have symbolic expressions with `Times`inside?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the first one doesn't work for me (even if I replace the comma with an ==) and the second works only for matrices (and not for higher rank tensors)

Comment: Try with `Flatten@Function[{a, b}, a == b, Listable][mat1, mat2]`

Comment: That's what I wanted to suggest and then looked to see if anyone did it and found your answer :-) +1.

Comment: 3 years late, but `Transpose[Flatten /@ {mat1, mat2}]` is equivalent to `Flatten[{mat1, mat2}, {{2, 3}, {1}}]`. :)

Comment: @OleksandrR. I must say, this answer was written before I had fully grokked [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/5) :)

Answer (score 5):

For instance:

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {4, 4}];
b = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {4, 4}];

MapThread[Equal, {a, b}, 2] // Flatten
(*
{False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
False, False, False, False, False, False, False}
*)
```

The above equates the matrices element by element. To see this, define

```
c = Array[Subscript[d, #1, #2] &, {4, 4}]
```

then try the code I gave, ie, `MapThread[Equal, {c, b}, 2]` and your code, `Thread /@ Thread[c == b] // Flatten`; they give the same answer. But yours does not work for numeric matrices: `Thread /@ Thread[a \[Equal] b] // Flatten` errors. To see why, trace what is happening: `Thread /@ Thread[a == b] // Trace` and you see it first evaluates `a==b`, then threads. So, if one of the matrices is symbolic, this works OK as the `Equal` returns unevaluated, then gets threaded; but if both are numeric, the `Equal[a,b]` evaluates to `False`, and then there's nothing to thread or flatten.

Thus, your code and Rojo's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3218/16) rely on one of the matrices being symbolic so that the `Equal[a,b]` part remains unevaluated. They don't equate `a` and `b` elementwise if they are numeric (not that this matters for what you want to do; I just thought it was worth mentioning).

Comment: I wonder why `MapThread` does not support levelspec `-1`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So do I...

Answer (score 5):

Since `Block` didn't work as I intended on packed arrays, here is another idea:

```
Inner[Equal, Flatten@A, Flatten@B, List]
```

Again `Inner` is faster than other options:

```
A = RandomInteger[15, {140, 130, 120}];
B = RandomInteger[15, {140, 130, 120}];

Inner[Equal, Flatten@A, Flatten@B, List]; //AbsoluteTiming

MapThread[Equal, {A, B}, 3]; //AbsoluteTiming

Equal @@@ Transpose[Flatten /@ {A, B}]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.3010172, Null}
>
> {0.4230241, Null}
>
> {0.4220242, Null}