# Block attributes of Equal

Tags: functions, evaluation, attributes

I answered [“Equating matrices (or higher order tensors) element-wise”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3217/121) with:

```
{A, B} = RandomInteger[3, {2, 4, 3, 2}];

Block[{Equal},
  SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];
  A == B
]
```

> ```
> {{{False, False}, {False, True},  {False, False}}, 
>  {{False, True},  {False, False}, {True, False}},
>  {{False, True},  {False, False}, {False, False}}, 
>  {{False, False}, {False, False}, {True, False}}}
> ```

But it fails if `A` and `B` are packed arrays:

```
{A, B} = Developer`ToPackedArray /@ {A, B};

Block[{Equal},
  SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];
  A == B
]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

One may observe that setting `SetAttributes[Equal, Listable]` outside of `Block` also fails to effect the `Listable` behavior.  This also applies to `Unequal` and `SameQ`.  This is of interest to me, but my prime concern is that despite the `Block`, `Equal` is being recognized and receiving special treatment.  I expected symbols localized with `Block` to behave generically.

---

- How does this fit into the main evaluation loop?
- How can I get get *true* "blocking" of a symbol such that it behaves generically within a scoping construct?
- What other symbols besides `Equal`, `Unequal`, and `SameQ` are handled differently?

Comment: Hehehehehehehehe +1

Comment: @Rojo I couldn't crack this nut myself.  Leonid, where are you?

Comment: Can not add much this time. It looks like `Equal` (and perhaps some other operators) are internally overloaded on packed array arguments for speed, in a way incompatible with the main evaluation sequence. I suspect that this was hard-wired to the system, so that such redefinitions are not even expressed as internal rules (amenable to `Block`). But these are all just guesses.

Comment: @Leonid thank you.  That's my operating assumption as well, though I find it troubling.

Comment: I think corner cases like this are to be expected for a high-level interpreted language which contains efficient data structures for special cases. You have to bypass the main evaluator as early as possible to be efficient, and at some point you have to make a choice which evaluation model to use. I am actually surprised that these corner cases are so few. A more consistent way to gain efficiency would probably be through making it possible to compile a larger subset of the language.

Comment: @Leonid I suppose then that the only thing "troubling" is my lack of knowledge of *Mathematica*. :-)

Comment: Oh no, this *is* troubling, because this sort of explicitly violates the semantics of the language (albeit in one of its darker corners). I was just saying that it is hard to avoid such violations in a language with two distinct efficiency scales. Compiled languages solve this by having interpreted REPL but also compilation to native code. Some interpreted languages solve it by having JIT compilers in them. The solution currently used by Mathematica probably suits Mathematica as a system but is hardly adequate for it as a general-purpose programming language, from a purist's viewpoint.

Comment: That is, provided that my guesses about hard-wiring this stuff are right, and this is not just a plain bug.

Comment: Using `Block[{Equal},SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];Equal[a_,b_]:=Hold[Equal[a,b]];A==B]//ReleaseHold` gives `{{{False, False}, {False, True}, {False, True}}, 
 {{False, False}, {False, False}, {True, False}}, 
 {{False, True}, {False, False}, {False, False}}, 
 {{False, True}, {False, False}, {False, True}}}`

Comment: @celtschk using `Trace` on your expression v. Mr. Wizard's shows that by redefining `Equal`, as you do, it is actually threaded over the lists, yet Mr. Wizard's is not. Using `SetSystemOptions["PackedArrayOptions" -> "UnpackMessage" -> True]` reveals that in both cases some unpacking does occur, but in Mr. W's case we get "Unpacking array with dimensions {1}" v. "Unpacking array with dimensions {4,3,2} in call to Equal" in your case. By redefining `Equal` it automatically unpacks the full array.

Comment: Almost every built-in function that has no visible definitions (e.g. downvalues, try `Thread`, `Outer`, `Flatten`, whatever) associated with it seems to have this behaviour.  I tested using `With[{f = Equal}, 
 Block[{f}, SetAttributes[f, Listable]; With[{r = f[a, b]}, Hold[r]]]]`.  This property of builtins can be removed by issuing any user-definition (as @celtschk showed above). Another common "unusual" behaviour of builtins is that their definitions take effect *after* any user-made definitions.

Comment: Since this seems to be a common feature of all builtins, maybe it's like this to be able to make optimizations for packed arrays.  Without this, packed arrays would always be unpacked when passed to a `Listable` function.  Which builtin is `Listable` that is also optimized for packed arrays I am not sure, I did not find it (I didn't look much either).  But if we find one, that could be a support for this hypothesis.

Comment: I just noticed another case where `Block` doesn't work as expected with built-in operations: `Block[{Plus},Hold@Evaluate[1+1]]` gives `Hold[2]` instead of `Hold[1+1]` (writing `Plus[1,1]` instead of `1+1` doesn't change that result). That one cannot even be circumvented with an user-definition: `Block[{Plus},Plus[a_,b_]:=plus[a,b];Hold@Evaluate[1+1]]` still gives `Hold[2]`, not `Hold[plus[1,1]]`.

Comment: @celtschk yet `Block[{Plus = z}, ToString[1 + 1]]` returns `"z[1, 1]"` -- I guess a lesson in this is that plain `Block[{x}, ...]` doesn't really clear everything it should, but giving something to replace it with (`{x = ...}`) helps.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: `Block[{Plus},Plus=z;ToString[1+1]]` also gives `"z[1, 1]"`. Therefore the difference seems to be between `OwnValues` and `DownValues`.

Comment: I am revising some tags around [tag:functions] and it seems like [tag:system-function] is only used here throughout the entire site. Do you have any special plans with it?

Comment: @István at least in the context of this question I have no justification for the "system-functions" tag over the existing "functions" tag.  Conceivably it may have a future meaning, such as using functionality of the system on which *Mathematica* is installed, therefore it should not IMO be a synonym.

Comment: That is not a conclusive answer :) Be reasonable: no one else uses this tag, so I would suggest removing it. You can reintroduce it any time when you feel like there is a serious background for it. Agreed or rejected?

Comment: A different epoch now and probably already noted but for the record it probably was just a bug: `A==B` returns (`False`) for both non-packed and packed arrays.

Answer (score 2):

you are good! Based on your comments, I crafted this:

```
Block[{Equal, H = Developer`ToPackedArray},
 SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];
 Equal[x_H, y_H] := 
  Equal[Developer`FromPackedArray[x], Developer`FromPackedArray[x]];
 a == b]
```

which works in both cases.

**Update**

Mr.Wizard said " I expected symbols localized with Block to behave generically." Although the above works, as mentioned in the comments, there is an observable difference between `Equal` and other user defined symbols in the rewrite/eval loop in regards to `Listable` and automatic unpacking of packed arrays. I played with different definitions and couldn't find why this happens.

```
Clear[f, g, h, z1, z2];
ClearAttributes[{z1, z2}, {Listable}];
f[a_, b_] := Block[{Equal, H = Developer`ToPackedArray},
   SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];
   Equal[x_H, y_H] := 
    Equal[Developer`FromPackedArray[x], 
     Developer`FromPackedArray[x]];
   Print[ a == b  // FullForm];
   a == b];
g[a_, b_] := Block[{Equal, H = Developer`ToPackedArray},
   SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];
   Print[ a == b  // FullForm];
   a == b];
h[a_, b_] := Block[{Equal = z1, H = Developer`ToPackedArray},
    SetAttributes[z1, Listable];
    Print[ a == b  // FullForm];
    a == b] /. z1 -> Equal;
i[a_, b_] := Block[{Equal = z2, H = Developer`ToPackedArray},
    SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];
    Print[ a == b  // FullForm];
    a == b] /. z2 -> Equal;
```

Then I did

```
{a , b } = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}};
{c , d} = Developer`ToPackedArray /@ {a, b};
```

which produces,

> In[211]:= f[a, b]
>
> List[Equal[1,1],Equal[2,3]]
>
> Out[211]= {True, False}
>
> In[212]:= f[a, c]
>
> List[Equal[1,1],Equal[2,2]]
>
> Out[212]= {True, True}
>
> In[213]:= g[a, b]
>
> List[Equal[1,1],Equal[2,3]]
>
> Out[213]= {True, False}
>
> In[214]:= g[a, c]
>
> Equal[List[1,2],List[1,2]]
>
> Out[214]= True
>
> In[215]:= h[a, b]
>
> List[z1[1,1],z1[2,3]]
>
> Out[215]= {True, False}
>
> In[216]:= h[a, c]
>
> List[z1[1,1],z1[2,2]]
>
> Out[216]= {True, True}
>
> In[217]:= i[a, b]
>
> z2[List[1,2],List[1,3]]
>
> Out[217]= False
>
> In[218]:= i[a, c]
>
> z2[List[1,2],List[1,2]]
>
> Out[218]= True

So one can see that there is a difference between `g[a,c]` and `h[a,c]`: in g `Equal` does not unpack, whereas in h the user-defined z1 does. I think all the other behaviours can be explained from the evaluation (rewrite) steps as explained in the Mathematica documentation.

Anyway, just wanted to comment finally that although Mr Wizard's is a fair claim. There are a number of areas where other than pure symbolic/rewrite manipulation is occurring, and that simply `Block` is not probably considering. For example -hope not to trivial for you-, `Block[{Equal}, ToExpression["?Equal"]]` still prints the `Equal` documentation, instead of a reference to an undefined symbol. So, like in this case, maybe `Equal` (and other built-ins) have special behaviour which `Block` is not touching.

Sorry, I will leave it as answer, but now probably I should say it is not...

**Update 2**

Actually, just checked that `Block` leaves ::usage untouched! So, if you do

```
f::usage = "Symbol f";
```

then

> Information[f]
>
> Symbol f

And if you do `Block` still you get the same

> Block[{f}, Information[f]]
>
> Symbol f

so `Block` and `Information` are *not* working together, even for user-defined symbols!

**Last update**

As noticed by some, symbols like `Plus` have special behaviour too. So this

```
Block[{Plus}, Print[Trace[Plus[1, 2]]]]; (* 1 *)
Block[{Global`Plus}, Print[Trace[Plus[1, 2]]]]; (* 2 *)
Block[{Global`Plus}, Print[Trace[Global`Plus[1, 2]]]]; (* 3 *)
```

produces

> {1+2,3}
>
> {1+2,3}
>
> {}

which demonstrates that `Plus` retains the built-in behaviour in 1 and 2, being really overridden only with a syntax like 3, which is not convenient. By the way, 2 generates a warning.

Bottom, line, to *answer Mr.Wizard's request* -I believe this answer was suggested in the comments- it seems the only generic way to override a built-in is to provide your own user defined symbol instead. If one wants to redefine, say Plus, IMHO it is not a burden as whatever definition one wants to introduce can be done with the user-defined symbol and still one has the convenience of the syntactic sugar. To wit

Block[{Plus = plus}, plus[0, _] := 0; Print[Trace[0 + 2]]];

which produces

> {{Plus,plus},plus[0,2],0}

So, I will leave it like this.

Comment: isn't this just another example of the observation from the comments - that *any* user definition will cause the array to be unpacked? For example using `Equal[x_dummy]=Null` will have the same effect

Comment: I'm sorry, but I agree with Simon.  I don't think this addresses the the heart of my question.

Comment: I thought the point of your question was if Equal had special behaviour in Block, that's what I understood.  I edited my answer to clarify this. Besides, I tried the code without the x_H case and it didn't work, so I disagree with the general unpacking behaviour mentioned.

Comment: Apologies, you guys were right @Mr.Wizard, there are observable differences between built-in symbols in `Block` as opposed to user defined. I wonder if there are more than the ones mentioned, or even if `Block` cannot fully *clear* a symbol in all areas of the Mathematica kernel - regardless if it is built-in or user-defined.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, see Update 2! I bet there is a negative answer to your question "How can I get true blocking of a symbol such that it behaves generically within a scoping construct?" - there is not such thing, even for user-defined symbols.

Comment: +1 for your efforts on this.  I think messages are a special case as these are meta-definitions rather than definitions or attributes upon the symbol itself.  Block changes the *definition* (and Attributes but only in a limited fashion as I discovered) of `f` but not the symbol itself.  That is, inside the block `f` is still `f` but theoretically "generic" -- nevertheless Messages still exist that reference this name.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard see what will be my **last update** about `Plus`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, what do you mean with Attributes in a limited fashion?

Comment: @Rojo I only meant the limitation illustrated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it helps. It's another ways to copy and change internal functions attributes using `Function`. Here we create a function `myEqual` just as `Equal` but listable, so we don't have to use `Block`:

```
{A, B} = Developer`ToPackedArray /@ {A, B};
myEqual=Function[Null,Equal[#1,#2],Listable];
A ~myEqual~ B
```

> {{{True,False},{False,False},{False,False}},{{False,False},{False,False},{False,False}},{{False,False},{False,False},{False,False}},{{False,False},{False,False},{False,False}}}

Note that `Null` inside `Function` is just an undocumented property. If you get more comfortable you can just use: `Function[{a,b},Equal[a,b],Listable];`

You can make my equal local, just as you did in your example:

```
{A, B} = Developer`ToPackedArray /@ {A, B};
Module[{myEqual},
    myEqual=Function[Null,Equal[#1,#2],Listable];
    A ~myEqual~ B
]
```

---

**Update**

As @OleksanrR. commented. A clever way to define `myEqual` is:

```
Function[Null, Equal[##], Listable]
```

So we don't have to restricted to 2 arguments.

Comment: Why not use `SlotSequence`? (Indeed, that would seem to be the main reason to use this form of `Function` outside of playing tricks with argument renaming.)

Comment: You are right. Updated. tks!