# GridBox/packed array behaviour

Tags: output-formatting

I have never used low-level formating functions, so this problem might have a simple solution. I'm currently pulling my hair out trying to solve it, however. Consider the following example:

```
foo = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]
(*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}*)

bar = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
(*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}*)

GridBox[foo] // DisplayForm
(*GridBox[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]*)

GridBox[bar] // DisplayForm
(*gives correctly formated output*)
```

Why does the DisplayForm depend on the way the list was created?

**Edit:**
I contacted WRI Technical support and got the following answer:

> GridBox is doing what it should do. Box forms interpret strings and boxes
>   and not Mathematica expressions. Thus there is no reason to expect GridBox
>   to interpret a packed array which is a compiled expression. Grid uses
>   GridBox for the formatting but unpacks first.

I guess the bottomline is, use Grid instead of GridBox if possible (just as I should have done), or unpack arrays in advance.

Comment: Wow, that's _weird_!

Comment: Seems like GridBoxes don't work well with packed arrays. Another packed array bug?

Comment: It's also contagious. If you set `foo1=foo` the weirdness happens with `foo1` as well.

Comment: Please tell me you can reproduce that...?

Comment: `foo===bar` yields `True`...

Comment: @sebhofer Reproducible for me.

Comment: Thanks for notification of the duplicate.  I hadn't been aware of this issue (or question). +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like `GridBox` doesn't work well with packed arrays. Or at least not with `DisplayForm`

```
r = RandomInteger[10, {4, 4}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[r]
rnp = Developer`FromPackedArray[r];
DisplayForm[GridBox[r]]
DisplayForm[GridBox[rnp]]
```

`DiagonalMatrix` returns a packed array

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

> True

So, I'd say it's a bug, but a workaround to ensure it all works fine is to wrap your variable in `FromPackedArray` before putting it in the `GridBox`

```
foo = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}];
GridBox[Developer`FromPackedArray@foo] // DisplayForm
```

Comment: Good catch, would never have thought of that...

Comment: Thanks @sebhofer. I had context of a similar bug that I found in a Mr.Wizard's answer, that ended up in him asking [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3261/block-attributes-of-equal). Seems like there are some corner cases when packed arrays are a little buggy, and one can only be safe by unpacking them manually. Hope they get fixed

Comment: I'll report it as a bug when I find the time...

Comment: Although it's not a bug, you definitely found the culprit :) Thanks again!

Comment: @sebhofer, why is it not considered a bug?

Comment: Rojo, Wolfram claims it's not a bug (see edit above). I don't know much about the logic of these low-level formatting functions, but it seems reasonable to me to have this hierarchic structure of GridBox, Grid,...

Answer (score 5):

```
foo = ToExpression[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]]
GridBox[foo] // DisplayForm
```

works in the docs it states In StandardForm, explicit GridBox objects are output literally.

Comment: Seems like applying `ToExpression` to packed arrays serves to unpack them