# Why can't I pass in a product of matrices in my modified matrixform?

Tags: programming, output-formatting, syntax

In attempt to build a function that would work like `MatrixForm` but would wrap a matrix with brackets, I tried the following function:

```
matrixform[mat_] := TraditionalForm[DisplayForm[RowBox[{
StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]], 
GridBox[mat], 
 StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]}]]]
```

This does what I want on an ordinary matrix, say `a={{1,2},{3,4}}`, as well as on `2a` and `a+a`. But if I pass in a product such as `a.a` it does not work properly. I have tried wrapping the product in `Evaluate`, and tried executing `a.a` separately and then passing in `%` and this has made no difference. Note that a better function `Composition[bracketF,Grid]` suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55599/how-to-input-and-output-partitioned-matrices-that-show-partitions-and-compute-as/55609?noredirect=1#comment160079_55609) lacks these issues. So the question is why can we not pass in a product of matrices into `matrixform`? This is my first time working with functions such as `StyleBox, GridBox, RowBox`, etc.

Comment: This seems to be another strange behavior, probably a bug.  I'll take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: Not a bug after all.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is present in both version 7 and version 10 (Windows).  Illustrated:

```
IdentityMatrix[2] // matrixform
```

[image]

```
{{1, 0}, {0, 1}} // matrixform
```

[image]

There *is* a difference between `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}` and (the evaluated form of) `IdentityMatrix[2]`: the latter is a packed array.

```
{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}  // Developer`PackedArrayQ
IdentityMatrix[2] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```

It seems that `GridBox` (or the Front End interpreting it) is not equipped to handle packed arrays.
Your original definition works if we unpack:

```
IdentityMatrix[2] // Developer`FromPackedArray // matrixform
```

[image]

You can therefore correct your definition by adding this:

```
matrixform[mat_?Developer`PackedArrayQ] :=
  Developer`FromPackedArray[mat] // matrixform
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring all of this out. Since it is a Duplicate, do I accept an answer still? I am guessing the reason `bracketF` from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55599/how-to-input-and-output-partitioned-matrices-that-show-partitions-and-compute-as) "works" is because it uses `ToBoxes` which gives box expressions and `GridBox` works on box expressions.

Comment: How is this not a bug? Mathematica goes a long way towards hiding all the packing/unpacking internals hidden from the user, who, without delving into the `Developer` context, does not have *any* tools or visual hints to distinguish them. In my opinion the message of that (or at least a perfectly justified expectation) is that they should behave identically wherever a list is expected. `GridBox` help page does not mention anything about requiring lists to be unpacked either.

Comment: @TheVee The official position is that it is not a bug, see [(4744)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4744/121).  The quoted statement includes *"Box forms interpret strings and boxes and not Mathematica expressions."* This seem to suggest that `GridBox[{{1, 2, 3}}]` is not valid either and it should be `GridBox[{{"1", "2", "3"}}]`.  Indeed `ToBoxes@Grid[{{1, 2, 3}}] // InputForm` shows that this is what `Grid` produces.  It is interesting that `GridBox[{{1, 2, 3}}] // DisplayForm` is accepted however.

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain this strange behaviour of `GridBox`. But replacing it with `Grid` I get the desired output (also with `a.a // matrixform`)

```
matrixform[mat_] := 
 TraditionalForm[
  DisplayForm[
   RowBox[{StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]], Grid[mat], 
     StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]}]]];
```

To align the numbers properly use `Grid[mat, Alignment -> Right]`

Comment: Thanks. I thought I tried Grid at one point but was somehow discouraged. I was under the impression that when working with `RowBox` and `StyleBox` that I had to use `GridBox`. I guess that was wrong.