# How can I use Max[] in a function that is passed a list not find the max of the list

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, functions

For most functions in `Mathematica`, passing them a list will call the function on each element of the list. For example:

```
ExampleFunction1[x_] := x + 1
ExampleFunction1[{1, 2, 3}] 
(* {2, 3, 4} *)
```

But things change when you use `Max[]`. For example if I have this function:

```
ExampleFunction2[x_] := Max[x, 4]
```

If I pass this a single number `x`, it will return either `x` or `4`, whichever is larger, but, as documented, if i pass it a list like this:

```
ExampleFunction2[{1, 3, 7}]
```

It will return 7. Instead I'd like it to return `{ 4, 4, 7}`.

How can I make my function so that `Max` uses an element of a list as its argument instead of the entire list?

Comment: Have a look at `Clip`, maybe it will help you.

Comment: You mean a listable function that only maps up to the innermost list?

Comment: Oh, I missed you actually wanted to find the max point to point against 4

Comment: Good Call. Clip[x, {4, Infinity}] works

Answer (score 7):

`Plus` is `Listable` while `Max` is not , look at `Attributes` :

```
Attributes @ Max
```

> ```
> {Flat, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected}
> ```

`Attributes` is `Listable` as well so this will be more informative : `Attributes@{Plus, Max, Attributes}`.

Moreover :

```
ExampleFunction2[x_] := Max[x, 4]
Attributes @ ExampleFunction2
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

In order to make your function `ExampleFunction2` working as you'd like you can set `Attributes` to it using `SetAttributes` (it won't change `Attributes` of `Max`) :

```
SetAttributes[ ExampleFunction2, Listable]
Attributes @ {ExampleFunction2, Max}
```

> ```
> {{Listable}, {Flat, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected}}
> ```

then it works nicely :

```
ExampleFunction2[{1, 3, 7}]
```

> ```
> {4, 4, 7}
> ```

Comment: Alternatively, `Block[{Max}, SetAttributes[Max, Listable]; etc]`

Comment: @Rojo just remember that will [fail with packed arrays](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3261/block-attributes-of-equal), e.g. ``x = Developer`ToPackedArray@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
Block[{Max}, SetAttributes[Max, Listable];
 Max[x, 4]
 ]`` returns `7`.  (Yes, I could have used `Range` but I want to make packing explicit.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, true, bad memory. I hope that get's fixed in V9 and I hope V9 happens some time soon

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `Max` just map it over the function:

```
ExampleFunction2[x_] := Max[#, 4] & /@ x

ExampleFunction2[{1,3,7}]

(*{4,4,7}*)
```

The only catch here, is you want your argument to be a list.

Also, if you have a multi-dimensional list, try:

```
ExampleFunction3[x_] := Map[Max[#, 4] &, x, {First@Dimensions@x}]

ExampleFunction3[{{1, 3, 7}, {2, 4, 8}}]

(*{{4, 4, 7}, {4, 4, 8}}*)
```