# Finding element-wise Max of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I need a `compare-operation` for two lists of same length (usually > 100000) which does the following:

> {2,3,5,4,1,8,7} `compare-operation` {1,4,6,3,2,8,8} = {2,4,6,4,2,8,8}

The resulting list has at each position the greater (or equal element in case both are equal) of the two lists (because 2>1,4>3,6>5,4>3,2>1,8=8,8>7).

How can that be done?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(13414)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13414/121), [(51541)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51541/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MapThread[Max, {{2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 7} , {1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 8}}]
```

> `{2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 8, 8}`

```
Thread[Unevaluated[Max[{2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 7} , {1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 8}]]]
```

also works. `Unevaluated` is necessary, otherwise `Max[...` evaluates, before `Thread` acts on it. On the other hand

```
Thread[Unevaluated[Max[list1, list2]]]
```

*does not work* for the same reasons.

```
list1 = RandomInteger[30, 1*^7];
list2 = RandomInteger[30, 1*^7];
MapThread[Max, {list1, list2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{6.302683, {28, 10, 21, 13 ...`

Not too bad for ten million elements. In fact, faster than constructing the lists.

In this simple case however, we can do **10 times better**:

```
(Max /@ Transpose@{list1, list2}) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `0.608412`

For a list with 2 dimensions the obvious solution is

```
MapThread[Max, {list1, list2}, 2] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `0.702000`

Timing is shown for a `10^3` by `10^3` list.

The *faster* solution uses the, so-to-speak, generalized transpose, which is achieved by using flatten with a matrix as the second argument:

```
Map[Max, Flatten[{list1, list2}, {{2}, {3}, {1}}], {2}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `0.109200`

As before, almost an order of magnitude faster. The general expression for `k`-dimensional lists would be:

```
Map[Max, Flatten[{list1, list2}, {{2}, {3}, ..., {k+1}, {1}}], {k}]
```

**Update 18.09.17**

Carl Woll's `ThreadedMax` is hard to beat, but exploiting `Compile`d listability comes close:

```
threadMax = 
 Compile[{{x1, _Integer}, {x2, _Integer}}, Max[x1, x2], 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

It is still a few times slower though and I'd recommend Carl's solution. Simple top-level functions with built-in listability are close to impossible to beat even with compiled functions and are more versatile in the datatypes they accept: e.g., the above `threadMax` will only work on packed arrays of integers.

If `Ramp` isn't available in your version of MMA, just like it is in mine (I'm on 10.2), I suggest the following implementation:

```
ThreadedMax[l1_List, l2_List] := 
 With[{diff = Subtract[l1, l2]}, 
  Check[UnitStep[diff] diff + l2, $Failed]]
```

I would similarly modify Carl's solution like so for better performance:

```
ThreadedMax[l1_List, l2_List] := Check[
    Ramp[Subtract[l1, l2]]+l2,
    $Failed
]
```

See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/26956) for further reading.

Comment: Dear LLlAMnYP, this is what I wanted.
Can that be done also with 2 dimensional lists e.g. Dimensions[list]={720,577}?

Comment: Do you mean element-wise comparisons at the second level of the lists? As in `{{1, 6},{3, 9}} ~~ {{2, 5}, {4, 1}} -> {{2, 6},{4, 9}}`?

Comment: You can imagine that I would have two grey level images of 720 rows and 577 columns and I want to produce an resulting image where each pixel brightness corresponds to the higher brightness value of the images.

Answer (score 7):

For threading the maximum of a list (or array) with a number, you'll be hard pressed to beat the following:

```
ThreadedMax[l1_List, l2_?NumericQ] := Clip[l1, {l2, Infinity}]
```

For example:

```
l1 = RandomReal[1, 10^8];

ThreadedMax[l1, .5]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.552601, Null}

For threading the maximum of 2 arrays, the following is the fastest approach I can think of:

```
ThreadedMax[l1_List, l2_List] := Check[
    Ramp[l1-l2]+l2,
    $Failed
]
```

Comparing with the answer by @LLlAMnYP:

```
l1 = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
l2 = RandomReal[1, 10^7];

r1 = ThreadedMax[l1, l2]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = MapThread[Max, {l1, l2}]; //AbsoluteTiming
r3 = Max /@ Transpose[{l1, l2}]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.089001, Null}
>
> {5.53821, Null}
>
> {0.602344, Null}
>
> True

For arrays with higher rank, we have:

```
l1 = RandomReal[1, {3000, 3000}];
l2 = RandomReal[1, {3000, 3000}];

r1 = ThreadedMax[l1, l2]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = MapThread[Max, {l1, l2}, 2]; //AbsoluteTiming
r3 = Map[Max, Flatten[{l1, l2}, {{2}, {3}, {1}}], {2}]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.096501, Null}
>
> {5.30103, Null}
>
> {0.694005, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Very nice improvement. Since you're using `Listable` operations inside your `ThreadedMax` definition, I see no reason to check the `Head` of the arguments. `ThreadedMax[l1_, l2_] := Check[Ramp[Subtract[l1,l2]]+l2,$Failed]` will cover all cases and probably give optimum performance, as per my update.

Answer (score 5):

If you are in 11.1 or later verion

```
ThreadingLayer[Max][{{2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 7} , {1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 8}}]
```

> `{2.,4.,6.,4.,2.,8.,8.}`

Of course,we have build-in method if you are in old verion

```
Internal`MaxAbs[{2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 7} , {1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 8}]
```

> `{2,4,6,4,2,8,8}`

Or

```
Random`Private`MapThreadMax[{{2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 7}, {1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 8}}]
```

will give a same result

Comment: +many if I could, this is a brilliant showcase of an undocumented `Internal` function. An extra ~3-fold speed increase.

Comment: Like net function too!

Comment: Of course, `MaxAbs` is `Max`**`Abs`**, but it seems that OPs use-case works with non-negative numbers anyway.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP See edit..

Comment: Nonexistent in 10.2, it seems.

Comment: Minimal overhead to handle negative values: ``With[{min = Min[list1, list2]}, 
   Internal`MaxAbs[Subtract[list1, min], Subtract[list2, min]] + 
    min]``