# Element-wise minimum of two matrices

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to compare two identically-shaped matrices and select the minimum of the two. This is an extension of a past question: [Element-wise max of two lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83236/finding-element-wise-max-of-two-lists), except I have three nested lists.

```
Data1 = {{{3, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}}, {{5, 2}, {3, 6}, {2, 4}}, {{13, 
2}, {34, 62}, {24, 14}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 8}, {3, 2}}}
Data2 = {{{2, 3}, {2, 14}, {2, 1}}, {{6, 4}, {2, 7}, {2, 4}}, {{13, 
2}, {34, 62}, {24, 14}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 8}, {3, 2}}}
```

My desired output is:

> {{{2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 1}}, {{5, 2}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}}, {{13, 2}, {34, 
>      62}, {24, 14}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 8}, {3, 2}}}

Comment: You say maximum, your example appears to be minimum.
`MapThread[Min, {Data1, Data2}, 3]`
Don't use uppercase initials on your symbols, bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @ciao I have adjusted the text to be consistent with minimum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $min(x,y) = x - (x - y)^+$ (where $a^+ = max(a,0)$),  you can use:

```
Data1 - Ramp[Data1 - Data2]
```

> {{{2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 1}}, {{5, 2}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}}, {{13, 2}, {34, 
>         62}, {24, 14}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 8}, {3, 2}}}

or

```
Subtract[Data1, Ramp @ Subtract[Data1, Data2]]
```

> {{{2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 1}}, {{5, 2}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}}, {{13, 2}, {34, 
>         62}, {24, 14}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 8}, {3, 2}}}