# Element-wise test on List elements

Tags: list-manipulation, map, operators

This question could sound pretty silly but I can't find a way to apply element -wise tests to a list.

For example if I digit

```
{0.6, 1.2}>1
{{0.6,1.2},{5,0.1}}>1
```

I would expect to obtain

```
{False,True}
{{False,True},{True, False}}
```

respectively, but it is not the case.

Of course I can define a function or using `Map`, but I can't believe there is not a core function providing this kind of result. 
Thank you for any indication

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2821/12

Comment: This question is a version of [(13414)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13414/121) and [(51541)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51541/121).

Comment: Applying `Map` at level `{-1}` covers both cases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To my knowledge, there aren't built-in versions for comparison operators that would be automatically threaded over lists. One reason for that is that Mathematica is a symbolic system, and every auto-simplification has a cost, because there may be cases when this isn't desirable.

It is relatively easy however to construct the behavior you want:

```
ClearAll[l];
l[f_] := Function[Null, f[##], Listable]
```

Now, you can call:

```
{{0.6, 1.2}, {5, 0.1}} ~ l[Greater] ~ 1

(* {{False, True}, {True, False}} *)
```

and similarly with other comparison operations.

Note that, since you didn't mention efficiency, I intentionally left this aspect out. If you have large numerical lists, there are vastly more efficient ways to perform the comparisons, making use of vectorization and packed arrays.

Comment: I don't fully get the sintax (I'm just a beginner) but this function does what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @dario [1/2] The syntax `a ~ f ~ b` is called infix notation, and is equivalent to `f[a,b]`, but sometimes looks more natural. Like in this case, where it allows to somewhat make up for the notational convenience of comparison operator symbols. The expression `a > b` can be equivalently rewritten as `Greater[a,b]` in Mathematica, and similarly for other operators. So, we could also write `a ~ Greater ~ b`, which doesn't look bad. Now, from this form, my suggestion is only one step further. The function `l` I proposed is similar in spirit to Python decorator. It takes another function and ...

Comment: @dario [2/2] ... makes it `Listable` - that is, wraps it in a pure function that has a `Listable` attribute. Due to the way evaluation sequence works in Mathematica, this leads to threading of the function over lists, before it gets applied to the individual elements. As a result, the construct `l[Greater]` would automatically work on lists of any dimensionality, compared to a single number - as well as for e.g. comparison of two lists with the same dimensions - like say `{1,3,5} ~ l[Greater] ~ {6,4,2}`. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: Is it correct to think of `l` as a function that defines a pure function? (`specifically, it looks like `l` uses the input `f` to define a pure function based on `f`?)

Comment: @user106860 I think, the simplest way to think of `l` is that it is similar to a decorator in python. It takes a function and returns a modified function which adds listability (which happens to be implemented using `Function`, but that's an implementation detail).

Answer (score 18):

The [`` BoolEval` ``](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/examples/id/31) package does exactly this. For example:

```
BoolEval[{0.6, 1.2} > 1]
(* Out: {0, 1} *)
```

and

```
BoolEval[{{0.6, 1.2}, {5, 0.1}} > 1]
(* Out: {{0, 1}, {1, 0}} *)
```

In order to return `True` and `False` instead of `0` and `1`, you can append `/. {0 -> False, 1 -> True}`.

Comment: This solution work as well as the one I've chosen as "best answer", and is probably more elegant. I haven't chosen this, though, because it requires additional packages. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 9):

### Depth 1

```
MapAt[Greater[#, 1] &, {0.6, 1.2}, {All}]
```

> ```
> {False, True}
> ```

OR

```
Thread[Greater[#, 1]] & @ RandomReal[2, 10]
```

> ```
> {True, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, True}
> ```

### Depth 2

```
MapAt[Greater[#, 1] &, {{0.6, 1.2}, {5, 0.1}}, {All, All}]
```

> ```
> {{False, True}, {True, False}}
> ```

OR

```
Thread[Greater[#, 1]] & /@ RandomReal[2, {3, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{True, True, False, True, True}, 
>  {True, False, False, False, False},
>  {False, False, False, False, True}}
> ```

### Depth n

```
f=MapAt[Greater[#, 1] &, #, Table[All, (Depth[#] - 1)]] &

f[{{{1.6, 0.2}, {3, 0.1}}, {{0.6, 1.2}, {5, 0.1}}}]
```

> ```
> {{{True, False}, {True, False}}, {{False, True}, {True, False}}}
> ```

```
f@RandomReal[2, Range[6]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OR

```
RandomReal[2, Range[4]] /. (w_Real -> w > 1)
```

Comment: `Map[Greater[#, 1] &, {{0.6, 1.2}, {5, 0.1}}, {-1}]`

Answer (score 8):

The first example can be done with

```
Thread[{0.6, 1.2} > 1]
```

$\ $`{False, True}`

For the second example `Map` has to be used for this approach, but maybe in a different way than you excluded in you question:

```
Thread /@ Thread[{{0.6, 1.2}, {5, 0.1}} > 1]
```

$\ $`{{False, True}, {True, False}}`

Answer (score 7):

Check `Positive`.

For `{0.6, 1.2}>1`, you may write:

```
Positive[{0.6, 1.2}-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

For the better read,I post this solution as an answer

`Map[Greater[#,1]&,{{0.6,1.2},{5,0.1}},{-1}]`

> {{False, True}, {True, False}}