# Greater operator should give greater element

Tags: functions

`4>3` gives `True`.

What is the "greater_operator" to obtain the result 4?

For lists accordingly:

`{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` "greater_operator" `{{5, 1}, {7, 2}}`

should give a resulting list: `{{5, 2}, {7, 4}}`

Comment: `Max[]` can do it, but it needs some assistance: `MapThread[Max, {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} , {{5, 1}, {7, 2}}}, 2]`.

Comment: ++1 if you wouldt turn this into an answer

Comment: (I've capped hours ago; if anyone wants to answer with that, you have my permission.) The fully general version goes something like `p1 = {{{9, 6}, {-7, 4}}, {{-5, 9}, {8, 2}}}; p2 = {{{3, -9}, {-9, -4}}, {{-7, 3}, {8, 8}}}; MapThread[Max, {p1, p2}, ArrayDepth[p1]]`.

Comment: Related: [(3217)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3217/121), [(23395)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/121),
[(95666)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95666/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get the desired behavior is to make the `Max` function `Listable`:

```
Unprotect[Max];
SetAttributes[Max, Listable];
lst1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; lst2 = {{5, 1}, {7, 2}};
Max[lst1, lst2]

{{5, 2}, {7, 4}}
```

You could also do the same thing a bit more safely by changing the `Max` function attributes only when needed. For instance:

```
max[list1_, list2_] := Module[{out}, Unprotect[Max]; SetAttributes[Max, Listable];
  out = Max[list1, list2]; ClearAttributes[Max, Listable]; out]
```

Comment: Also @FredSimons: I think it is much cleaner to make `Max` `Listable` in the way [Leonid did in this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95666/element-wise-test-on-list-elements/95667#95667).

Answer (score 4):

A slight improvement of the answer of bill s, without unprotecting Max:

```
max[list1_, list2_] := Block[{Max}, Attributes[Max] = {Listable}; Max[list1, list2]]

max[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 1}, {7, 2}}]

(* {{5, 2}, {7, 4}} *)
```

Comment: @Karsten. Unfortunately, I missed that contribution of Leonid, something that is always highly regretable. Thank you for calling my attention to it. Indeed, the solution then becomes surprisingly simple: max=Function[Null, Max[##], Listable].

Answer (score 4):

Here is `J.M.`'s direct solution:

```
MapThread[Max, {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} , {{5, 1}, {7, 2}}}, 2]
```

Here is `J.M.`'s more general solution:

```
p1 = {{{9, 6}, {-7, 4}}, {{-5, 9}, {8, 2}}};
p2 = {{{3, -9}, {-9, -4}}, {{-7, 3}, {8, 8}}};
MapThread[Max, {p1, p2}, ArrayDepth[p1]]
```

Although not the question, it was referenced at the beginning of the post, so here's how you could apply `>` instead of `Max`:

```
MapThread[#1 > #2 &, {p1, p2}, ArrayDepth[p1]]
(* {{{True, True}, {True, True}}, {{True, True}, {False, False}}} *)
```

Comment: Upvoted, of course. :)

Comment: @J.M. Oh, thanks! I worked hard on this one. :) I waited the requisite amount of time, I feel, and since no one else took advantage of your kind offer, I figured I would!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose all your digtal is non-negtive,I give a undocumental function for this

```
lst1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
lst2 = {{5, 1}, {7, 2}};
Internal`MaxAbs[lst1, lst2]
```

> {{5,2},{7,4}}