# Maximum brightness of two gray scale images

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, image-processing

I am using the answer of [bill s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s) in [Greater operator should give greater element](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97918/greater-operator-should-give-greater-element).

Here he showed the example:

```
lst1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; lst2 = {{5, 1}, {7, 2}};

max[list1_, list2_] := Module[{out}, Unprotect[Max]; SetAttributes[Max, Listable];
  out = Max[list1, list2]; ClearAttributes[Max, Listable]; out];

max[lst1, lst2]

{{5, 2}, {7, 4}}
```

Now I would like to apply it to two images:

image 1:

[image]

image 2:

[image]

I though the code below would show the superposed image with max intensity at each pixel.

```
imageData1=ImageData[image1];
imageData2=ImageData[image2];

maxImage=Image[max[imageData1,imageData2]]
```

The result is a message:

> Image::imgarray: The specified argument 1.` should be an array of rank
>   2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers. >>

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternative solutions: You could use `ImageApply` on images:

```
ImageApply[Max, {i1, i2}]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0239, Null}

Or `MapThread` on lists:

```
Image[MapThread[Max, ImageData /@ {i1, i2}, 2]]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0231, Null}

And, somewhat surprisingly this uses 2 multiplications and 3 additions per pixel:

```
 (
   {d1, d2} = ImageData /@ {i1, i2};
   comp = UnitStep[d1 - d2];
   Image[comp*d1 + (1 - comp)*d2]
   ); // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00069, Null}

and is still > 30 times faster.

Even more surprisingly (to me):

```
(
  comp = Binarize[ImageSubtract[i1, i2], 0];
  ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[comp, i1], 
    ImageMultiply[ColorNegate@comp, i2]]
 ); // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0017, Null}

Is *slower* than the double precision arithmetic version above. Apparently, `ImageAdd` and friends aren't very efficient.

Comment: I vote for your `{d1, d2}` solution. I tested a superposition of sequentiell gray scale images (286 png 8bit images, each 347*347 pixels). The code `{d1, d2} = ...` is in total about 4 times faster than using `ImageApply[Max, {img1, img2}]`. See https://imgur.com/MhJApXv and https://imgur.com/9Thol7v.

Answer (score 6):

It's simpler than that, since you can use the built-in image processing function ImageApply:

```
img1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBsDH.png"];
img2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Vm6.png"];
ImageApply[Max, {img1, img2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Upvote.I have to say the `ImageApply` is low efficiency function.Maybe `ImageAdjust[ImageAdd[img1, img2]]` is enough

Comment: @yode -- it may not be particularly efficient to run, but it is very efficient to write. And it is also very flexible since you can use any function (with the right number of inputs and outputs), not just Max.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please see my comment below nikies answer. Do you know why your code in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97918/greater-operator-should-give-greater-element is not applicable?