# Can this code be compiled?

Tags: image-processing, compile

The following code reads all gray scale png images inside of a folder and then calculates the maximum intensity for each pixel and finally export the resulting image. This is until now the fastest code that can do that.

Please see also the answer from [nikie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/242/nikie) in: [Maximum brightness of two gray scale images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119994/maximum-brightness-of-two-gray-scale-images)

My question: can this code be compiled?

```
SetDirectory["f:\\images_dir\\"];

fNames = FileNames["*.png"];

numFiles = Length[fNames];

image = Import[fNames[[1]]];

newImage = ImageMultiply[image, 0];

Do[

  {d1, d2} = ImageData /@ {image, newImage};

  comp = UnitStep[d1 - d2];

  newImage = Image[comp*d1 + (1 - comp)*d2];

  image = Import[fNames[[i]]];

  , {i, 2, numFiles}

  ];

Export["f:\\images_dir\\analysis\\super.png", newImage, "png"],
```

Comment: Sadly, like many useful things, image related code can't be compiled

Comment: This is really sad. I compared the solution from nike with the software ImageJ: if the system memory is not exceeded ImageJ (in Java) is for some reason "much" faster. Would it be helpful first to read all images in memory instead of doing it in the loop?

Comment: Did you try timing the individual parts? My guess would be that the arithmetic is as fast ImageJ, as it's done on packed arrays, but `Import` is much much slower. If so, compiling isn't the solution, replacing `Import` is...

Comment: How about importing image data directly (once for all files, in the Main Evaluator, like `Import[#, "Data"]&/@fNames`) and then you can work on the raw data using a compiled version of the rest of your code. A custom `ImageMultiply` can be easily written that works directly on an integer array. Then you `Export` again on the ME.