# Applying boolean logic to a 2D array

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

How can I make a function that creates a particular size 2D matrix that determines `True` or `False` if a random value between `0` and `1` is at or below a certain number? Below is what I have written but when I put in values all I get is a column of `trues`.

```
initializeGrid[rows_Integer, columns_Integer, value_] := 
  Module[{table, booleanTable},
  table = Table[RandomReal[], {r, rows}, {c, columns}];
  booleanTable = BooleanTable[x <= value, table];
  Return[booleanTable]
]
```

Comment: See also [Element-wise test on List elements](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95666/element-wise-test-on-list-elements/95667#95667).

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to get a matrix of `True` and `False`:

```
Table[RandomReal[] < 0.2, {i, 10}, {j, 10}]
```

Change the `0.2` to your desired threshold and the `10` to your desired matrix size.

Or use `RandomChoice` to directly choose between True and False with a given probability:

```
RandomChoice[{0.8, 0.2} -> {True, False}, {10, 10}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[123]
ran = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];

PaddedForm[TableForm[ran], {3, 2}]
```

[image]

Replace all numbers below `n` with `False` or `True` otherwise

```
n = 0.6;
Unitize @ Threshold[ran, n] /. {1 :> True, 0 :> False} // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [BoolEval package](https://bitbucket.org/szhorvat/booleval).

```
Needs["BoolEval`"]

matrix = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]
(* Out: {{0.965037, 0.544295, 0.191919}, {0.270774, 0.582857, 
  0.261769}, {0.4165, 0.935575, 0.243333}} *)

BoolEval[matrix < 0.5]
{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}
```

You can of course replace zeros with `False` and ones with `True` (`/. {0 -> False, 1 -> True}`) but don't do it unless you really need it, because those values are not stored as efficiently internally. If you do that then the list will no longer be "packed".