# Relational operators on vectors

Tags: syntax, inequalities

How do I use relational operators on vectors?

```
{1, 2, 3} > {0, 1, 2}
(*outputs {1, 2, 3} > {0, 1, 2}*)
```

More generally, I want `{a,b}>{c,d}` to be equivalent to `a>c && b>d`. Or, I would want to say `vars>0` where `vars` is a vector of my variables and that one constraint forces them all to be strictly positive. How might I achieve that?

Comment: Related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95666/81)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
And @@ Thread[{a, b} > {c, d}]

(* a > c && b > d *)
```

Comment: Great! And copying that for the `vars>0` example: `And @@ Thread[vars > Flatten[ConstantArray[0, {Length[vars], 1}]]]` works.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a new operator ( `⪢`,alias `\[NestedGreaterGreater] )` that is a generalisation of the built-in `>` :

```
NestedGreaterGreater[x___] := And @@ Thread[Greater[x]]
```

This permits interesting operations :

- `{a, b} ⪢ {c, d}`

> (a > c) && (b > d)

- `{a, b} ⪢ {c, d} ⪢ {e, f}`

> (a > c > e) && (b > d > f)

- `{a, b}  ⪢ c  ⪢ {d, e}`

> (a > c > d) && (b > c > e)

For clearity some parenthesis have been added in the previous results.

Comment: by the way, I'm discovering that `1>x>2` gives `False` (with x symbolic)

Comment: I have tried this operator on a lot of special cases : it seems to be robust. If someone find a problem, I'm interested. Thanks.

Comment: I have not studied the precedence of the operator. Don't hesitate to use parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [BoolEval](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/examples/id/31) package. You'd use it like this:

```
Needs["BoolEval`"]
FreeQ[BoolEval[{1, 2, 3} > {0, 1, 2}], 0]
(* True *)
```

Or

```
Times @@ BoolEval[{1, 2, 3} > {0, 1, 2}] == 1
```

The point being that `BoolEval` returns a 1 or a 0 for each comparison, representing true or false. If there are no zeroes that means that all comparisons were true.

> How do I use relational operators on vectors?

`BoolEval` is a general answer to this question.

If you want a more compact syntax you could implement `BoolEvalAnd`, `BoolEvalOr` etc. along the lines of the solution above.