# List of lists elementwise greater/smaller than

Tags: list-manipulation, map, boolean-computation

I have two lists

```
a = {{3,1,2},{5,1,3},{4,1,1}}
b = {{4,0,3},{4,2,2},{5,0,2}}
```

And would like to compare each element within

```
If{a>b,1,0}
```

expecting the result

```
{{0,1,0},{1,0,1},{0,1,0}}
```

but it doesn't work, how can I get this type of comparison?

Comment: [Strongly related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95666/element-wise-test-on-list-elements)

Comment: you could use `1-UnitStep[b-a]`?

Comment: Of course, fixed.

Comment: @kglr yep, that achieves the result, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Boole@Positive[a-b]
```

> {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}

```
1-UnitStep[b-a]
```

> {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}

Answer (score 3):

kglr took the fast, vectorized operations. Here are some less optimal ones that you can have a look at for fun or for learning:

```
Boole@MapThread[Greater, {a, b}, 2]
```

> {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}

```
Boole@Apply[Greater, Transpose[{a, b}, {3, 2, 1}], {2}]
```

> {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}