# Help understanding overloading of Atomics within Block

Tags: core-language

Usually `h @@@ {f[1, 2], f[3, 4]} === {h[1, 2], h[3, 4]}` but this is not the case when `f` is `Complex`: `h @@@ {1 + 2I, 3 + 4I } === {1 + 2 I, 3 + 4 I}`
Since `Complex`is an atomic and as documentation for `Apply` states: *Applying to atomic objects that do not have subparts effectively does nothing*

Using `Block` to replace `Complex` with `complex` gives result as expected for non-atomic case:

```
Block[{Complex = complex},
 List @@@ {Complex[1, 2], Complex[3, 4]}
 ]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} *)
```

But then how come replacing `Complex` with `List` while not `Apply`-ing does not give the same result?

```
Block[{Complex = List},
 {Complex[1, 2], Complex[3, 4]}
 ]
(* {Complex[1, 2], Complex[3, 4]} *)
```

As it would have for a non-atomic head:

```
Block[{f = List},
 {f[1, 2], f[3, 4]}
 ]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} *)
```

Comment: Funnily enough, if I use `TracePrint[Block[{Complex = List}, {Complex[1, 2], Complex[3, 4]}]]`, the replacement happens. Quite odd, this evaluation...

Comment: `With[{Complex = List}, {Complex[1, 2], Complex[3, 4]}]` works, but still does not explain the behavior. `Block[{Complex = complex}, {Complex[1, 2], Complex[3, 4]}]` does not work either, so `Apply`ing seems to be the key

Comment: This is a very strange behavior. For example, this works: `Block[{Complex}, Complex := List; {Complex[1, 2], Complex[3, 4]}]`, and after that, the original example works too. Looks like some changes are not propagated properly.

Comment: As one might expect, this general technique also doesn't work if the head `Complex` exists only by implication, as in a packed array.

Comment: @Oleksandr I think that's a given, as atomic objects do not evaluate, and `Block` only affects things that do; right?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it may be interesting to compare with `Unprotect[Graph];
Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}] // AtomQ (*True*);
Graph = hh;
Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}];
Quit[]` then. Even though Mathematica says the expression is an atom, we do get the substitution of heads in this case.

Comment: Apparently `Complex[1, 2]` is not equivalent to `1 + 2I`. `Block[{Complex = f}, List @@@ {Complex[1, 2], 3 + 4 I}]` gives `{{1, 2}, 3 + 4I}` I thought that was just a syntactic difference

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Perhaps related to `Graph` having subparts while `Complex` does not. (i.e. you can't get the real part of a `Complex` with `(1+2I)[[1]]`)

Comment: @ssch you can also not take the first part of an expression with head Graph.

Comment: *Mathematica* is full of surprises, isn't it!

Comment: More surprises: `Block[{Complex}, Plus[3, Complex[0, 4]]] + 2`-> `5 + Complex[0, 4]`. Which is crazy. Also, `Trace` lies about how `3 + 4 I` becomes `Complex[3,4]`. What a mess.

Answer (score 2):

This is hardly a complete answer but I suspect this is the result of special handling of the symbol `Complex`, much as there is [special handling of packed arrays.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/121)

Remember that `Block` only affects things that evaluate, e.g. `Block[{a = 1}, Hold[a, b, c]]` returns `Hold[a, b, c]`.  I believe that `Complex` may be passed over when it comes to evaluation.  Consider this example outside of `Block`:

```
Unprotect[Complex];
Complex = ff;
Complex[1, 2]
Quit[]
```

> ```
> 1 + 2 I
> ```

The head `Complex` is never evaluated to `ff` here.  Interestingly, with a delayed definition it is:

```
Unprotect[Complex];
Complex := ff
Complex[1, 2]
Quit[]
```

> ```
> ff[1, 2]
> ```

I cannot think of a reason within the *normal* evaluation process for this to be, hence my suspicion of special handling.

Comment: Try immediate evaluation after you try the delayed one. I also made all these experiments you present here, but somehow I feel that this is not the whole story.

Comment: @Leonid Surely this is not the whole story, as stated.  Do you agree that there appears to be special handling taking place?

Comment: I am not sure about it.

Comment: It should probably be noted that even `Unprotect[Complex];
Complex = hh;
Complex` -> Complex. Same goes for Integer.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom This is not so simple. Check this: `Unprotect[Complex];Complex := hh;Complex`and then `Complex =.;Complex = hh;Complex`.