# Button evaluation inside DynamicModule

Tags: dynamic, code-review

Someone know why this `Button` works when clicked:

```
testModule1[]:=DynamicModule[{button, x="",randomGrid},
    button=Button["Create table",x=RandomInteger[10,{3,3}]//MatrixForm];
    Deploy@Panel@Dynamic@Column[{button,x}]
]
testModule1[]
```

[image: test1]

and this not:

```
testModule2[]:=DynamicModule[{button, x="",randomGrid,ff},
    ff:=(x=RandomInteger[10,{3,3}]//MatrixForm);
    button=Button["Create table",ff];
    Deploy@Panel@Dynamic@Column[{button,x}]
]
testModule2[]
```

[image: test2]

I have some big functions to put into `x`, and I would like to organize my code in the second way.

Comment: It is my understanding (correct/incorrect) that `SetDelayed` doesn't work inside the `DynamicModule`.

Comment: You can use `ff[]:=...` and then `ff[]` instead of `ff` inside the button code, and that will work. This does not explain however why `OwnValues` don't work.

Comment: Ok, here is a kind of an explanation. As @MikeHoneychurch noted, the delayed evaluation is performed in fact immediately (or at least so it looks to me too). Then, `x` is assigned some random matrix, and `f` is out of the game for the `OwnValues` scenario. You can look at the generated box expression in the FE for your button, to see this. However, for `DownValues`, while the assignment is again performed immediately, the `DownValues` get stored by `DynamicModule` with the help of `DynamicModuleValues` option. This keeps `f[]` in the button code operational.

Comment: Yes!.. ff[] works, DynamicModules are very strange (or would be all MMA evaluation system?)!.. Tks @Leonid

Comment: @Murta No problem. I agree that `Dynamic` can be not quite intuitive. I usually find workarounds for what I need from it, but I can't say that I have any deep understanding of it.

Comment: Hm.. This appears not to be a difference between `Set[symb, Unevaluated[code]]` and `SetDelayed[symb, code]`. [A difference](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27268/4330)

Answer (score 14):

Well, [Mike Honeychurch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/77) and [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81) have pretty much covered the ground, but I have one thing to add, which, while based only on observed behavior, I think helps explain what's going on.

`Set` and `SetDelayed` both create `OwnValues` is the form `HoldPattern[symbol] :> code`.  The difference is that `code` is unevaluated in the case of `SetDelayed`.  `DynamicModule` stores ownvalues as initialization assignments, `symbol = value`.  This makes a difference because the expression `value` is or appears to be created by executing `code`.  So in the case of `SetDelayed`, the `code` ends up being evaluated anyway, not when the `SetDelayed` is first evaluated, but when the ownvalue it creates is stored in the `DynamicModule` output.

One can observe this in the following

```
testModule3[] := 
 DynamicModule[{button, x = "", ff}, 
  ff := (Print["Boo!"]; x = RandomInteger[10, {3, 3}] // MatrixForm);
  button = Button["Create table", ff];
  Deploy@Panel@Dynamic@Column[{button, x}]]
testModule3[]
(* --> Boo! *)
(* Panel with non-working button *)
```

The "Boo!" is printed even though button was not pressed.  If `Module` replaced `DynamicModule`, the `Print` statement would not have been executed and "Boo!" would not be printed.

The problem (for the designers of `DynamicModule`) can be seen in this:

```
Clear[x]

ff1 = x + 4;
x = 3;
ff2 = x + 4;
ff3 := x + 4;
OwnValues@ff1
OwnValues@ff2
OwnValues@ff3

(* {HoldPattern[ff1] :> 4 + x} *)
(* {HoldPattern[ff2] :> 7} *)
(* {HoldPattern[ff3] :> x + 4} *)
```

One can see that `ff1` and `ff3` are equivalent, even if not strictly identical.  But why should this be a problem?  Why not store these ownvalues in the form they are above?  In that case, `DynamicModule` would work just like the rest of *Mathematica* (just like `Module` in [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478)'s second solution).  The answer I think is fairly simple, but for me it is just a guess: **speed**.  Just as `Compile` is limited to a simpler subset of functionality, so is dynamic interactivity and what the front end can handle.

The kind of assignment the front end can do without communicating with the kernel is probably just a simple assignment (such as in C, say).  It does not create a pattern but stores a value in the front end.  Primarily I think the developers have in mind number assignments, but clearly any expression is allowed on the RHS.  This allows such things as [`Animator`s to be efficient](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/why-animator-smoothes-dynamic-updates-or-how-to-make-pacman-drink-beer/23861#23861), for instance.  In the case of complicated RHS expressions, the front end asks the kernel to evaluate it and send the value back.  Efficiency in this sort of end-use case and minimizing computational overhead is clearly part of the design of the `Dynamic` system.

That's how the basic principles seem to me.  That they are part of the design can be inferred from [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#368838921),
and [the following section](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#440620996) in [Advanced Dynamic Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html).
The motivations I have guessed at may be off, and there may be further internal considerations that are yet hidden from me.

---

P.S.  Here's another variation to solve the OP's problem, which is consistent with the explanation above:  Use `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` to mimic the behavior of `SetDelayed`.  Whether `Set` or `SetDelayed` is used to define `ff` does not matter.  The "value" of `ff` in either case is the held expression, which is what is stored in the output cell (and can seen via Cell > Show Expression).

```
testModule4[] := DynamicModule[{button, x = "", ff},
  ff := Hold@(x = RandomInteger[10, {3, 3}] // MatrixForm);
  button = Button["Create table", ReleaseHold@ff];
  Deploy@Panel@Dynamic@Column[{button, x}]]
```

Comment: Tks Michael. Very elucidative explanation.

Comment: +1, especially for the workaround/solution. If this is done for reasons of speed, I guess I dislike this choice.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks.  I added a reference supporting the speed hypothesis.  I would like it better if the references for `Set`, `SetDelayed`, and/or `DynamicModule` mentioned this limitation.

Answer (score 7):

There are many issues arasing while creating complex `DynamicModule`s. Usually I'm not even sure what to ask about.

This is how I would do this in order to avoid putting procedures inside `Button`:

```
    testModule2[] := DynamicModule[{randomGrid, x = "", button},
                            button = Button["Create table", ff];
                            Deploy@Panel@Column[{button, Dynamic@x}]
                            , Initialization :> (

                                ff := (x = RandomInteger[10, {3, 3}] // MatrixForm);

                                                 )

                                  ]
```

The less content wrapped with `Dynamic`, the better.

Of course it is not an answer to your question. I think Mike Honeychurch is right but I miss some kind of tutorial "how to make efficient use of scoping constructs and Dynamic for CDF creating".

**Why do I think it is important?**, because good luck with only `DynamicModule` and minimal content wrapped with `Dynamic` if you want to scope all names. Notice, that in above code **`ff` is not scoped**. If you need this I recommend adding `Module`.

```
  testModule2[] := Module[{ff},  
                       DynamicModule[{randomGrid, x = "", button},
                        button = Button["Create table", ff];
                        Deploy@Panel@Column[{button, Dynamic@x}]
                       , Initialization :> (     
                          ff := (x = RandomInteger[10, {3, 3}] // MatrixForm);
                        )]]
```

**Leonid Shifrin's observation** about `DownValues` and `OwnValues` is striking. It is good to know that. It can help you make such code with only `DynamicModule`, however I like to have main structure of the CDF on top while procedures etc. at the end. The code is more transparent then, at least IMO.

Comment: what does randomGrid refer or relate to? It is not in the expressions and code works without it.

Comment: @ubpdqn it is from the question code :)

Comment: +1, using `Initialization` is in my opinion the most natural solution.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom New note. scoping `ff` inside `DynamicModule` is possible, we just have to create `DownValues` instead `OwnValues`: `ff[]:= ...`. Not sure why though

Answer (score 5):

Unless I am mistaken (which is entirely possible) I recall reading somewhere that `SetDelayed` is treated as `Set` within `DynamicModule`.

When I take your second block of code and use `Module` instead of `DynamicModule` it seems to work as you want (but `x` etc are now kernel variables of course).

Comment: This toy code is a small part of a CDF file. So I need the Dynamic part. The ff[] Leonid solution works nice tks!

Answer (score 2):

*I don't know if I like my interpretation of the examples below anymore. I will just leave them here though*

Here is more crazyness. I think Michael explains quite well what happens. The only thing new this first section shows is that new symbols get created sometimes, which makes it seem functions point to the wrong thing, but that actually does not matter.

```
DynamicModule[{button, x = 0, ff, `},
 ff := (++x);
 var = Hold[x];
 var2= z;
 button = Button["setX", ff];
 Dynamic[Column@{button, x, Hold[x], Hold[x], var, OwnValues[ff], z, var2}]
 ]
```

> ```
> Hold[FE`x$$213]
>
> Hold[FE`x$$213]
>
> Hold[x$314]
>
> {HoldPattern[FE`ff$$213] :> 1}
>
> FE`z$$225
>
> z$1236
> ```

Conclusions: It is possible for a variable to point to the wrong thing, like with var, or var2. ff does point to right thing, but it's code gets evaluated. Probably: The pointing to the wrong thing is **not** caused by the `DynamicModule` changing it's x all the time. I suppose it really wants to evaluate the code attached to symbols and not have it refer to any of the used symbols.

**DownValues**

Also note

```
DynamicModule[{gg = 0, x},
 OwnValues[gg] = {HoldPattern[gg] :> x};
 Dynamic[{OwnValues[gg], Hold[x]}]
 ]
```

> ```
>  {{HoldPattern[FE`gg$$270]:>FE'x$$270},Hold[FE`x$$270]}
> ```

but

```
DynamicModule[{gg = 0, x = 0},
 OwnValues[gg] = {HoldPattern[gg] :> x};
 Dynamic[{OwnValues[gg], Hold[x]}]
 ]
```

> ```
>  {{HoldPattern[FE`gg$$271]:>0},Hold[FE`x$$271]}
> ```

It seems it does **not** matter if we set something using `OwnValues` or in the regular way, using `Set` or `SetDelayed`. It seems that a function definition can even be changed afterwards, like in

```
DynamicModule[{gg = 0, x},
 OwnValues[gg] = {HoldPattern[gg] :> x};
 x = 0;
 Dynamic[{OwnValues[gg], Hold[x]}]
 ]
```

> ```
> {{HoldPattern[FE`gg$$312]:>0},Hold[FE`x$$312]}
> ```

**Order of evaluation**

The order of evaluation seems only to depend on the order in which they appear in the list of local symbols in the first argument of `DynamicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[{gg, x},
 x := (Print["x"]; {2});
 gg := (Print["gg"]; First@HoldComplete[x]; Print["ggDone"]);
 ]
```

> ```
> gg (*print*)
>
> x (*print*)
>
> ggDone (*print*)
>
> x (*print*)
>
> Null
> ```

and

```
DynamicModule[{gg, x},
 x := (Print["x"]; {2});
 gg := (Print["gg"]; First@HoldComplete[x]; Print["ggDone"]);
 ]
```

> ```
> x (*print*)
>
> gg (*print*)
>
> x (*print*)
>
> ggDone (*print*)
>
> Null (*print*)
> ```

We also see that it uses the "old" definitions of symbols to generate the definitions of the new symbols. I suppose it never does use a new definition in the definition of another new symbol.

I am lost :). I don't think I like this much.

Comment: @Kuba again, thanks for editing :). I really like the solution of the code blocks inside the "orangy blocks" :). Now the variables with a `Context` (and backtick) in front of them display beautifully. I'll see how you did it.

Comment: You are welcome :) ">"+ 5 " "