# Make dynamic controls from existing list

Tags: dynamic

I have a list of variables (`c1`,`c2`,`c3`,`c4`), each with its own range of possible values and each being a possible control.

I need to pick two of them and make the remaining ones controls in a `DynamicModule`. I tried to use suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552074/656841) but I didn't mange to make the last step work.

```
DynamicModule[{allC, lC, fC, sC},
  allC = {{{c1, 1, "c1"}, {1, 2}}, {{c2, 10, "c2"}, {10, 20}}, 
          {{c3, 100, "c3"}, {100, 200}}, {{c4, 1000, "c4"}, {1000, 2000}}};
  lC = Range[Length[allC]];
  With[{controlGenerate = Function[{var, initialValue, str, range}, 
                                    Control[{{var, initialValue, str}, range}], HoldAll]},
    Column[{controlGenerate[fC, 1, "First", lC],
            controlGenerate[sC, 2, "Second", DeleteCases[lC, _?(MemberQ[{fC}, #] &)]],
            (* The line below works as I expected *)
            Dynamic@allC[[DeleteCases[lC,_?(MemberQ[{fC,sC},#] &)]]],
            (* The line below doesn't work as I intended *)
            (controlGenerate[#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[1, 3]], #[[2]]] & /@                  
               (allC[[DeleteCases[lC, _?(MemberQ[{fC, sC}, #] &)]]]))
            }
           ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Well, the easiest thing seems to use the in-place evaluation on your second line: `(controlGenerate[...]&/@...) /. p_Part :> With[{eval = p}, eval /; True]`.

Comment: Do you want an improvement of your code or a solution that fits the description?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin This returns controls on all 4 variables, not just on the two left after the selection. Also, it doesn't work if I re-evaluate the whole `DynamicModule`.

Comment: @Kuba If you have a better way or a different approach, please do share !

Comment: @b.gatessucks Sorry, I did not look at this carefully enough. One thing I am sure of is that code generation is one of the best options for building Mathematica UI-s, since those are (possibly complex) Mathematica expressions. Alas, no time right now, but I might be able to revisit this one later.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks Leonid. (As it has happened a lot of times before,) I feel that if I make this work I'll be a  master of `DynamicModule`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I have some problems with `Control` are you interested in `Slider`s or `SetterBar`s, or the `Control` is the key here?

Comment: @b.gatessucks and about solution, no I don't have it yet but I want to be the `DynamicModule` master too! :)

Comment: @Kuba I can use `SetterBar` (though I wouldn't know why it's different).

Comment: @Kuba Let's keep pestering Leonid then.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution for `Setter`, or `Slider`, or any other that does not have `HoldFirst` attribute like `Control`.

Probably you can `Block` this attribute or deal with this using those replacements/evaluations in place, but I can't, I must start using those some time :)

Other important difference is that I'm not keepeing variable's names  in the list. Those variables are just `c[i]` in order to handle them easily via `Table`/`Array`.

```
DynamicModule[{fC = 1, sC = 2, lC, controlGenerate},
       allC = {{1, 2}, {10, 20}, {100, 200}, {1000, 2000}};
       lC = Range[Length[allC]];

       Column[{
               Dynamic@controlGenerate[Dynamic@fC, lC],
               Dynamic@controlGenerate[Dynamic@sC, Complement[lC, {fC}]],

               Dynamic@Table[With[{i = i}, controlGenerate[Dynamic@c[i], allC[[i]]]], 
                             {i, Complement[lC, {fC, sC}]}],
               Table[With[{i = i}, Dynamic@c[i]], {i, 4}]
                }]
       ,
       Initialization :> (   
                SetAttributes[controlGenerate, HoldFirst];
                controlGenerate[var_, range_] := SetterBar[var, range];
                         )
       ]
```

[image]

- there is `Complement` instead of `DeleteCases` in general it will not be the same but here I used it only for code transparency,
- also for transparency I skipped labels, you can easily add them
- `Dynamic@controlGenerate` <- `Dynamic` here probably could be skipped if you can initialize controlGenerate at start, but even that I've asked a question ["What is the right way to construct DynamicModule"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30079/5478) I'm still struggling with it often.

Looking forward to your comment.

Comment: I know, I know, the fun is with creating those controls with list you've provided. I think it is good for training but if it comes about creating applications I usually use buil-in solutions because it is possible to do what we want with them. Sometimes I just have to forget about habits or feelings about syntax and such cooperation works well :)