# Generate a dynamic interface with sliders out of a list of rules

Tags: dynamic

I would like to generate a function which takes a list of rules as input and generates sliders which are altering the values of the list. Then I would like to use this function in an dynamic module as input. 
This can be used as a dynamic way to generate a user interface for a model which is constantly evolving and I don't won't to hardcode the GUI and change it every time.

So here is a minimal example:

input:

```
ruleslist = {"valu1" -> 1, "value2" -> 2};
rangelist = {"valu1" -> {0, 2}, "value" -> {0, 5}};
ruleslist2 = {"valu3" -> 10, "value4" -> 20};
rangelist2 = {"valu4" -> {0, 20}, "value4" -> {0, 50}};
```

the function

```
rulestoinput[ruleslist_, ranges_, output_] := 
DynamicModule[{values, numInputFields, sliderlistn, names, 
origvalues, rangeslist},

origvalues = ruleslist[[All, 2]];
numInputFields = Length@ruleslist;
names = ruleslist[[All, 1]];
rangeslist = ranges[[All, 2]];

Do[values[i] = ruleslist[[i, 2]], {i, numInputFields}];
Panel@Column@
Flatten@{Column@{names[[#]], Dynamic[values[#]], 
      Slider[Dynamic[values[#]], rangeslist[[#]]]} & /@ 
   Range[numInputFields],
  Button["save settings", 
   output = 
    Flatten@Table[{names[[i]] -> values[i]}, {i, numInputFields}]]}
]
```

the dynamic module which uses the "rulestoinput" function and uses their results to Run something.

```
DynamicModule[{output1, output2, result},

Panel@Column@{rulestoinput[ruleslist, rangelist, output1],
Dynamic@output1,
rulestoinput[ruleslist2, rangelist2, output2],
Dynamic@output2,
Button["Run", result = Flatten@{output1, output2}],
Dynamic@result
}

]
```

The interface looks like this

[image: how it looks]

It works like this, but I don't want to press the "save settings" before "Run".

It would be good if just by clicking the Run button that the output1 and output2 would be updated from the sliders. 
I guess I am doing something wrong with the dynamic module. I searched for how to pass results from one Dynamic module to another, without success.

Of a slightly different approach. Here the results are not yet passed from the rulestoinput2 function to the "Run" button.

```
rulestoinput2[ruleslist_, rangelist_] := 
DynamicModule[{x = Table[ruleslist[[i, 2]], {i, Length@ruleslist}]},
Column[{Row[
 Table[With[{i = i}, 
   Slider[Dynamic[x[[i]]], rangelist[[i, 2]]]], {i, 1, 
   Length@ruleslist}]],
Dynamic@Thread[ruleslist[[All, 1]] -> x]}]]

DynamicModule[{result},

Panel@Column@{
rulestoinput2[ruleslist, rangelist],
rulestoinput2[ruleslist2, rangelist2],
Button["Run", 
 result = Flatten@{"new ruleslist 1", "new ruleslist 2"}],
Dynamic@result

}

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question by reading the answer to [Make dynamic controls from existing list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32587/make-dynamic-controls-from-existing-list?rq=1).

So I guess the answer to my question is to define the functions internally in the dynamic module with the HoldFirst attribute.

```
DynamicModule[{controlGenerate, ruleslist = ruleslist, 
ruleslist2 = ruleslist2, result, controlfromList},


Panel@Column[{Dynamic@ruleslist,
Dynamic@ruleslist2,
Dynamic@controlfromList[ruleslist, rangelist],
Dynamic@controlfromList[ruleslist2, rangelist2],
Button["Run", result = Flatten@{ruleslist, ruleslist2}],
Dynamic@If[Length@result >= 1, result, "press Run"]
}]

, Initialization :> (SetAttributes[controlGenerate, HoldFirst];
controlGenerate[var_, range_] := Slider[var, Last@range];
SetAttributes[controlfromList, HoldFirst];
controlfromList[ruleslist_, rangelist_] := 
Column@(Column@{Row@{ruleslist[[#, 1]], " ", 
        Dynamic@ruleslist[[#, 2]]}, 
      Dynamic@controlGenerate[Dynamic@ruleslist[[#, 2]], 
        rangelist[[#]]]} & /@ Range[Length@ruleslist])
)]
```

The interface then looks like this and expands dynamically as the ruleslist and rangelist are changed.

[image]