# DynamicModule Initialization is not executing when expected?

Tags: dynamic, variable-definitions

```
DynamicModule[{totalpages, pagesize},
 StringJoin[{"of ", ToString@totalpages, "."}],
 Initialization :> (pagesize = 5; 
   totalpages = Ceiling[Length[Range[456]]/pagesize];)
 ]

(* "of totalpages$443602." *)
```

As I understand `DynamicModule`, `totalpages` will be created from the scoping list when the code is executed. Then before the output is first displayed the `Initialization` option code will be executed which should set a value to `totalpages`.  Finally the output will be displayed.

However, the result I appear to be getting is that the `Initialization` code is not being called; only the scoping code. Or perhaps it is being called after the output is displayed. In any case I'm not getting the expected result.

What have I misunderstood?

It is interesting that the following works. However I can't use a `pagesize` variable in this case.

```
DynamicModule[{totalpages = Ceiling[Length[Range[456]]/5]},
 StringJoin[{"of ", ToString@totalpages, "."}]
 ]

(* "of 92." *)
```

Version 10.2 - Will be installing 10.3 later this week.

Comment: @Kuba With that nugget I have placed the `StringJoin` in a `Dynamic@Refresh[ #, None ]` which has solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/what-is-the-right-way-to-construct-dynamicmodule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour we see is due to the fact that the expression referencing `totalPages` has dynamic dependencies, but it is not wrapped in `Dynamic` itself.  The simple fix is to add `Dynamic` in front of `StringJoin`:

```
DynamicModule[{totalpages, pagesize},
 Dynamic@StringJoin[{"of ", ToString@totalpages, "."}],
 Initialization :> (pagesize = 5; 
   totalpages = Ceiling[Length[Range[456]]/pagesize];)
 ]

(* of 92. *)
```

However, it is much more interesting to examine the aspects of `DynamicModule` that explain the peculiar results we see.  In particular, the exhibited expressions reveal some of the localization strategies used at different stages of the `DynamicModule` evaluation process.

**Discussion**

For the discussion that follows, we will use an expression that reveals three important stages that occur during `DynamicModule` evaluation:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y = "y-eval"}
, {ToString[x], x, Dynamic[x], ToString[y], y, Dynamic[y]}
, Initialization :> (x = "x-init"; y = "y-init")
]

(* {"x$123", x$$, "x-init", "y-eval", "y-eval", "y-init"} *)
```

The results `"x$123"`, `x$$` and `"x-init"` correspond to the three stages in question.  An outline of the sequence of events is as follows.

**Stage 1: Initial Evaluation**

As per the documentation of `DynamicModule`, the expression is first evaluated after localizing all variables as if by `Module`.  This generates the symbols `x$123` and `y$123`.  Only latter is assigned a value.

The body of the `DynamicModule` is evaluated with these bindings in place.  `ToString[x]` captures the normally unobservable symbol name `x$123` in a string:

```
(* {"x$123", x$123, Dynamic[x$123], "y-eval", "y-eval", Dynamic[y$123]} *)
```

**Stage 2: Placeholder Localization**

The preceding result will be used to build the actual dynamic boxes.  Any local variables are renamed again to become so-called "placeholders":

```
(* { "x$123", $CellContext`x$$, Dynamic[$CellContext`x$$],
 "y-eval", "y-eval", Dynamic[$CellContext`y$$] } *)
```

Placeholders are necessary because a rendered `DynamicModule` can be duplicated by copy-and-paste, each copy needing to use different variables.  Placeholders are replaced by such unique variables when rendered for display.

**Stage 3: Display**

When the `DynamicModule` becomes visible, the placeholders are resolved, and the initialization form is evaluated.  Both `x$$` and `y$$` receive values, but only `Dynamic` parts of the expression will reflect those values.  That is why we see the final result which, when rendered, shows the non-dynamic reference to the placeholder `x$$` as an unevaluated symbol:

```
(* {"x$123", x$$, "x-init", "y-eval", "y-eval", "y-init"} *)
```

The present response has glossed over some details in the interest of brevity.  There are more than three stages, and some of the stages operate upon box forms instead of the simple expressions shown above.  [(75323)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75323/142) discusses some of those details in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

`//InputForm` is often helpful as well in a user is uncertain about what is happening