# How to include Initialization in DynamicModule

Tags: dynamic

I want to learn some of the basic rules for construction `DynamicModule`  code. I have looked at [Kuba's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/what-is-the-right-way-to-construct-dynamicmodule/30133#30133) post and feel overwhelmed by it. My ultimate goal is to use Switch in a `DynamicModule` that will provide different GUI's, each of which would plot equations produced by different algorithms.

So I began my journey by trying to transform the following `Manipulate` code to `DynamicModule` code:

```
Manipulate[
Plot[Evaluate[x[t, u]], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
Exclusions -> None],
{{u, 1, " "},  {1 -> A, 2 -> B, 3 -> C}},
TrackedSymbols :> {u, f},
Initialization :> (
x[t_, u_] := Switch[u,
  1, Sin[2 \[Pi] t],
  2, SquareWave[t],
  3, TriangleWave[t]];
)
]
```

The `DynamicModule` code that I came up with doesn't work. For starters, I dpn't know where to place the `Initialization` code. As you can see my my futile attempt, I lack understanding of the basic structure of `DynamicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[{},
Dynamic@Plot[x[t, u], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
Exclusions -> None],
{{u, 1, " "}, {1 -> A, 2 -> B, 3 -> C}},
Initialization :> (
x[t_, u_] := Switch[u,
  1, Sin[2 \[Pi] t],
  2, SquareWave[t],
  3, TriangleWave[t]];
)
]
```

Some guidance is needed.

Comment: That topic is quite old and may be vague, I will have to rephrase all that in context of what I've learned about GUIs creation in MMA. But going back to the question, `Initialization` is in a good place but you have to take care about `Controls` spec. While `Manipulate` translates `{u, 1, "  "}` to GUI and puts it next to the body, in `DynamicModule` you have to do this manually. Use `Grid/Row/Column/Panel` for positioning and `Slider/PopupMenu` and friends for those controllers.

Comment: If you are not very familiar with `Dynamic` functionality, my advice is to start off with `Manipulate`.  It's fine for simpler GUIs for personal use, for class demonstrations, and so forth.  However, if you keep running up against the limitations of `Manipulate` (and not just the limits of your knowledge), or if you are creating a commercial or business product, in which reliability and robustness are important, then you will need the control over things that you get with `DynamicModule`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by **Kuba** you have to take charge of the controls when `DyanmicModule` is used.

Here is a simple example from the documentation on `DyanmicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[{x}, {Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For your particular example below is a method that uses `Column`. Note that using `Initialization` will set the global value of the function `x`.

```
DynamicModule[
 {
  u
  },

 Column[{
   Dynamic@Plot[Evaluate[x[t, u]], {t, 0, 2},
     PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
     Exclusions -> None,
     ImageSize -> 400],

   SetterBar[Dynamic[u], {1 -> A, 2 -> B, 3 -> C}]
   }, Alignment -> Center
  ],

 Initialization :> (
   x[t_, u_] := Switch[u,
     1, Sin[2 \[Pi] t],
     2, SquareWave[t],
     3, TriangleWave[t]
     ]
   )

 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very helpful. Your example was much better than any of the others I've seen in the Wolfram documentation.