# Append new simulation into CDF without resetting current simulations

Tags: cdf-format

I need to duplicate a simulation inside one `DynamicModule`. I believe it's simpler to understand using an toy example. Here is the start screen:

[image]

Now if I play with `a` value, like this...

[image]

and then press `Add` button, I get:

[image]

with the first module reset.

Someone know how can I preserve the `Manipulate`'s states, when I `Add` or `Remove` an iten?

Here is my current code:

```
DynamicModule[{myCDF,controls,grid,btn},
    myCDF[]:=Manipulate[Plot[Sinc[a x],{x,0,10}],{{a,1},1,10}];
    grid={myCDF[]};
    btn["Add"]=Button["Add",AppendTo[grid,myCDF[]]];
    btn["Rem"]=Button["Remove",If[Length[grid]>1,grid=grid[[1;;-2]]]];

    controls=Grid[{{btn["Add"],btn["Rem"]}}];
    Dynamic@Panel[Column[{Grid[Transpose@{grid}],controls}]]
]
```

Comment: The problem is that for my real code is with `DynamicModule` (and can't use manipulate due to pack import). Tks

Comment: +1 good problem. Putting `Print` inside `myCDF` shows it only gets called once per adding a new plot, so everything should have worked as you expected.

Comment: As an FYI `SetDelayed` doesn't work within the body of a `DynamicModule`. You need to use `Initialization`.

Comment: Referrence to @Mike's statement: [evaluation inside `DynamicModule`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29129/5478)

Comment: Hmm, would `NotebookWrite` and `NotebookDelete` be an acceptable solution? (So each manipulate would be in it's own cell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay after the comments here is a rewrite that delivers what you need in a relatively simple way. You have mentioned that in your real life example you are not using `Manipulate`. Good. I don't like it so I'll use `DynamicModule`. So I'll start with a new version of `myCDF`:

```
myCDF[Dynamic[var_], num_] := DynamicModule[{a = var[[num]]},
  Panel@Column[{
     Manipulator[Dynamic[a, (a = #; var[[num]] = #) &], {1, 10}],
     Framed[
      Dynamic@
       Plot[Sinc[a x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> num],
      Background -> White,
      FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7]]
     }]
  ]
```

the value of `a` gets carried over to the next version of `myCDF`. `var` is a list of the initial values of `a` in each plot. Stick this all in a small `DynamicModule` (I have only included the "Add" button. Adding the remove should be straight forward, just `Drop` and `Decrement`).

```
DynamicModule[{var = {1}, i = 1, grid},

 grid = {myCDF[Dynamic[var], 1]};

 Column[{
   Dynamic@Column[grid],
   Button["Add", AppendTo[var, var[[-1]]]; ++i; 
    grid = myCDF[Dynamic[var], #] & /@ Range[1, i], ImageSize -> 100],
   Button["Remove", If[Length@var>1,var=Drop[var,-1]; --i;
grid = Drop[grid,-1]], ImageSize -> 100]
   }],

 Initialization :> {myCDF[Dynamic[var_], num_] := 
    DynamicModule[{a = var[[num]]},
     Panel@Column[{
        Manipulator[Dynamic[a, (a = #; var[[num]] = #) &], {1, 10}],
        Framed[
         Dynamic@
          Plot[Sinc[a x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300, 
           PlotLabel -> num],
         Background -> White,
         FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7]]
        }]
     ]}]
```

And this now works fine:

[image]

Comment: That's something but Murta is probably looking for a grid of independent animations, that's how I've understood it. Do you know why this preserves the state of manipulate?

Comment: This `LocalizeVariables -> False` is interesting, but I need they to be independent as @Kuba stated.

Comment: @Murta while that makes sense now that I spend a minute thinking about it, it was not mentioned in the question -- you only asked about preserving the states. Let me think about it over morning coffee.

Comment: @Murta please see update. This delivers what you asked for.

Comment: Tks Mike, nice way. I hope you don't mind, I added `Button["Remove"]` into the code. +1!

Comment: @Murta this is a simple answer that solves your toy problem with all variables **local**. If it does not solve your real problem then you will need to provide more information

Answer (score 5):

### Introduction

I present two methods below.  The new way has some advantages over the old way.  The original is a straightforward method that maintains a variable that stores the states of the copies of the `DynamicModule`/`Manipulate` `myCDF`added, which is similar to [Mike Honeychurch's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/77/mike-honeychurch) answer.  (The primary difference is that mine injects the state variable into the definition of `myCDF` and Mike's passes it as an argument, which seems a better way.)  The problem with these two methods is that the existing `myCDFs` are all replaced by new ones when another is added or one is removed.  This would be a problem if they take a long time to initialize.  Another is if `myCDF` has many state variables.  They all have to be updated.  The new way adds a new `myCDF` or removes the last one, but it leaves all the others intact without regenerating them.  This seems the right behavior to strive for.  The code is only slightly more complicated than the OP's starting point.

The problem is that the thing you want to copy is a front end object, not a kernel variable.  You can copy front end objects from the front end (select/copy) and paste them into the front end manually.  I don't know how to do this programmatically.  Perhaps there are undocumented functions that give access to the dynamic objects in the front end.

The problem with `grid` being a kernel variable is that the code in the `Manipulates` each set their variable `a` equal to `1` on instantiation by the front end.  Whenever `grid` is changed by `AppendTo`, all of the `Manipulates` are re-instantiated by in the front, which resets the values of `a`.

### New way

Instead of a `Grid` or even a simple list, here is a way using a sort linked list structure that ends with a pair of buttons.  The add button replaces the pair with a new `Manipulate` and another pair buttons.  (Actually, it switches views using `PaneSelector`.)  The remove button cause the parent to switch back, replacing the `Manipulate`/`Button` combo with another pair of buttons.

One particular odd problem was getting the remove button linked back to the parent.  If you don't do something to make the variable `sel` unique, the symbol that gets passed around is `` $CellContext`sel$$ ``.  If that symbol is passed to the new `DynamicModule` in the call

```
newMan[Dynamic @ sel]
```

then the symbol for `oldsel` and `sel` will be the same!  And the remove button is linked to the current element and not the parent.  I thought of various ways to get around this: Use `Module` for `sel` and inject and `Unique` symbol with `ReplaceAll`.  All gave red highlighting, a warning for a local scope conflict.  They all seemed to work, on this example at least.  I chose to present the one with `Function`.  (I had to choose one.)  Another odd problem is that without `ImageSize -> Automatic`, the `ImageSizeCache` of the enclosing `Dynamic` is not resized automatically.  I don't know if that's a bug, nor exactly why the `ImageSize` option fixes it.

```
ClearAll[newMan, myCDF];

myCDF = Manipulate[Plot[Sinc[a x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 1, 10}];

newMan[] := newMan[Dynamic[0]]; (* initial call *)
newMan[Dynamic[oldsel_]] :=
 Function[{sel},
   DynamicModule[{addbtn, rembtn, sel},
    sel = "buttons";
    addbtn = Button["Add", sel = "manipulate"];
    rembtn = Button["Remove", oldsel = "buttons", Enabled -> oldsel =!= 0];

    Column[{myCDF, PaneSelector[{
        "buttons" -> Grid[{{addbtn, rembtn}}], 
        "manipulate" -> Dynamic @ newMan[Dynamic @ sel]},
         Dynamic @ sel,
         ImageSize -> Automatic]}]

    ]] @ Unique["sel"]

Panel@newMan[]
```

### Original way

The first way I could figure out how to work around this limitation was to keep track of all the states of the `Manipulates` that are created.  If the `Manipulate` has many state variables, perhaps this might be aided by auxiliary functions.  In any case, I hope following might help in the actual use case. The state variable `a0` is updated whenever one of the `Manipulates` reevaluates.  In addition to a state variable, I added `Initialization` code that makes sure each `Manipulate` is properly initialized whenever they are recreated after `grid` is appended to.

```
DynamicModule[{myCDF, controls, grid, btn, a0, i},
 i = 0;
 myCDF[] := With[{j = ++i},
   If[j == 1, a0 = {1}, AppendTo[a0, Last@a0]]; 
   Manipulate[Plot[Sinc[(a0[[j]] = a) x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 1, 10}, 
    Initialization :> (a = a0[[j]])]];
 grid = {myCDF[]};
 btn["Add"] = Button["Add", AppendTo[grid, myCDF[]]];
 btn["Rem"] = Button["Remove", If[Length[grid] > 1, grid = grid[[1 ;; -2]]]];
 controls = Grid[{{btn["Add"], btn["Rem"]}}];
 Dynamic @ Panel[Column[{Grid[Transpose @ {grid}], controls}]]]
```

Comment: It is horrible that there is no simple way to do this. :/

Comment: tks Michael. Your new solutions worked just nice. In my problem, `myCDF` is actually another dynamic module. @Kuba, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is exactly what you were hoping for, but it might constitute a work-around. It basically let's you add/remove little static snapshots of the contents of the `Manipulates` (rather than active `Manipulates` themselves).

```
plotA[a_] := Plot[Sinc[a x], {x, 0, 10}];
DynamicModule[{controls, grid, btn},
  myCDF = Manipulate[aGlob = a; plotA[a], {{a, 1}, 1, 10}];
  grid = {myCDF};
  btn["Add"] = Button["Add", AppendTo[grid, plotA[aGlob]]];
  btn["Rem"] =  Button["Remove", If[Length[grid] > 1, grid = grid[[1 ;; -2]]]];
  controls = Grid[{{btn["Add"], btn["Rem"]}}];
  Dynamic@Panel[Column[{Grid[Transpose@{grid}], controls}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be a helpful improvement to the appended plots to have them labeled using the PlotLabel option to plot included in the code below:

```
plotA[a_] := 
Plot[Sinc[a x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions"];
DynamicModule[{controls, grid, btn}, 
myCDF = Manipulate[aGlob = a; plotA[a], {{a, 1}, 1, 10, 1}];
grid = {myCDF};
btn["Add"] = Button["Add", AppendTo[grid, plotA[aGlob]]];
btn["Rem"] = 
Button["Remove", If[Length[grid] > 1, grid = grid[[1 ;; -2]]]];
controls = Grid[{{btn["Add"], btn["Rem"]}}];
Dynamic@Panel[Column[{Grid[Transpose@{grid}], controls}]]]
```

[image]