# Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered

Tags: plotting, evaluation, warning-messages

I'm new to *Wolfram Mathematica* so the the question may seem quite simple.

I define the following function:

```
d[i_, j_] := 
 Sum[α^(i + j - 2 k) (-1)^(-k) Sqrt[i!] Sqrt[j!]/((i - k)! (j - k)! k!), {k, 0, Min[i, j]}]
```

Then, when I set `α = 0` and try to evaluate `d[0, 0]` I get the following warning:

> Power::indet: Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered.

How can I input the condition `Power[0,0]=1` in my function ?

Please help!

Comment: Could add alpha as a symbolic parameter, and eval symbolically before substituting a value. `d[i_, j_, alf_] := Module[{aa}, Sum[aa^(i + j - 2 k)*(-1)^(-k)*Sqrt[i!]
*Sqrt[j!]/((i - k)!*(j - k)!*k!), {k, 0, Min[i, j]}] /. aa->alf]                

In[16]:= d[0,0,0]                                                               

Out[16]= 1`

Comment: [(8403626)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8403626/121)

Answer (score 14):

Although it is best to avoid this when possible, using the undocumented function `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` you can temporarily add a rule to `Power`:

```
α = 0;

d[i_, j_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{Power},
  Unprotect[Power];
  Power[0, 0] = 1;
  Sum[α^(i + j - 2 k) (-1)^(-k) Sqrt[i!] Sqrt[j!]/((i - k)! (j - k)! k!), {k, 0, 
    Min[i, j]}]
 ]

d[0, 0]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Be aware that user rules for System functions may be ignored when working with packed arrays.  See: [Block attributes of Equal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/121)

Generally better is to use a proxy replacement for `Power` with your own behavior:

```
Attributes[myPower] = {Listable};
myPower[0, 0] = 1;
myPower[x_, y_] := x^y;

d[i_, j_] :=
 Sum[myPower[α, (i + j - 2 k)] (-1)^(-k) Sqrt[
    i!] Sqrt[j!]/((i - k)! (j - k)! k!), {k, 0, Min[i, j]}]
```

The `Listable` attribute makes sure that zeroes in vectors and matrices are also handled in the way we defined:

```
In[2]:= myPower[0, {{1, 1}, {1, 0}}]

Out[2]= {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}
```

Comment: The OP's coding gives me `1` for `d[0,0]`. Maybe she or he only had a dirty kernel?

Comment: @eldo I think you forgot to also start with `\[Alpha] = 0` as specified.

Comment: Thank you so much for the best answer!

Comment: Since the second part of your post seems to be the definite answer (and the safest) for these kinds of questions ([this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148609/89) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64179/89)), I've included the more general case. Hope you don't mind it!

Comment: Also, do you have any idea how to make `myPower` compilable or use it in a `CompiledFunction`?

Comment: @István Thanks for the addition.  I frankly don't do a lot with compilation but I'll try to give that some attention; don't get your hopes up!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this definition does not work for myPower[0.,0]

Comment: @ABCDEMMM That's true.  As with many of my answers I did not intend this to be an exhaustive definition ready for deployment as-is in production code.  You might add a rule like `myPower[__?PossibleZeroQ] = 1` to handle additional cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation of @Daniel's answer from his comment:

```
α = 0;
Block[{α}, d[0, 0]]
```

> 1