# How to set a shared variable Power (a modified one)?

Tags: functions, parallelization, kernel

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0|0., 0|0.] = 1 ;
Protect[Power];

Table[0^0, {i, 5}]
```

No problem at all.

```
 ParallelTable[0^0, {i, 5}]
```

becomes a problem.

How can I set this for all kernels?

Thanks!

Comment: May very seriously break built-in functions or alternatively the rule could magically disappear at any time without warning. I would not recommend this approach. Instead `Block` `Power` as some other function with the required behavior.

Comment: @OleksandrR.  Is MMA using this `Power` of 0^0 somewhere as a trick? Why would it seriously break built-in functions? I am a bit curious. As Maple define 0^0 to be 1. So no adjustment is need. I dont want to argue about why this definition is need sometimes. But I can't think of any harm if we simply define 0^0=1.

Comment: I think this definition is fine as long as everyone agrees on it. But in reply to your opening question: we simply can't know. So, by all means do this, but preferably not by directly re-defining the built-in `Power`.

Comment: Have you tried the method I proposed here?: [(60575)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60575/121).  I didn't write that with parallel computation in mind but I think it would work, though I have no time to properly test this now.

Comment: @OleksandrR. For the moment, I think I will stick to your `Block Power` method. I dont want anything unexpected to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Put the protect/unprotect into the table:

```
ParallelTable[Unprotect[Power]; Power[0 | 0., 0 | 0.] = 1; Protect[Power]; 0^0, {i, 5}]
```

I'm not sure how to do it globally, but you can make it a bit less painful if ParallelTable has to be called many times:

```
setPow := (Unprotect[Power]; Power[0 | 0., 0 | 0.] = 1; Protect[Power];);
ParallelTable[setPow; 0^0, {i,5}]
```

Comment: Thanks. Would there be a more "global" way of doing it? What if I have many calls of such "ParallelTable"? It would not be very efficient to type that for every single call.