# Indeterminant expression encountered in Summation

Tags: warning-messages, summation

I have a function that I'm trying to find an explicit form for the coefficients in its power series expansion.  On paper, it is a long calculation so I decided to write up the formula in mathematica.  One of the issues that I'm having is below.  In the expression I have 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{kx}$$
Since I'm trying to extract the coefficients (using Normal Series commands), I rewrite the exponential as a series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^\infty{k^j}\frac{x^j}{j!}$$
The codes are below (using n=10)

```
   Sum[E^(k*x), {k, 0, 10}]

 1 + E^x + E^(2 x) + E^(3 x) + E^(4 x) + E^(5 x) + E^(6 x) + E^(7 x) + E^(8 x) + E^(9 x) + E^(10 x)
```

Now if I rewrite it using the power series representation

```
 Sum[Sum[(k^j) (x^j)/j!, {j, 0, \[Infinity]}], {k, 0, 10}]

 Power::indet: Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered. >>

 E^x + E^(2 x) + E^(3 x) + E^(4 x) + E^(5 x) + E^(6 x) + E^(7 x) + E^(8 x) + E^(9 x) + E^(10 x) + \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\),\(j = 0),\(\[Infinity]\)]\*FractionBox[\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(0\), \(j\)]\SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(j\)]\), \(j!\)]\)
```

You can see that the calculation is suppressed because it is identifying $k^j$ as $0^0$.  But this is not a problem when I leave the exponential as is.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `SeriesCoefficient[]` not work for your function?

Comment: I don't want to pull out the coefficient.  I already know the coefficients for all powers of $x$. I'm trying to write an explicit formula.  I know how to extract coefficients using mathematica.   but I want to see if my explicit formula works.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Then, to avoid $0^0$, why not explicitly pull out the offending terms? Something like `11 + Sum[(k x)^j/j!, {k, 0, 10}, {j, 1, ∞}]`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quite hacky way... introduce a dummy variable `q` which gets set to zero later (effectively like using a `Limit`)

```
Sum[Sum[((k + q)^j) (x^j)/j!, {j, 0, \[Infinity]}], {k, 0, 10}] /. q -> 0

(* Result 1 + E^x + E^(2 x) + E^(3 x) + E^(4 x) + E^(5 x) + E^(6 x) + E^(7 x) + E^(8 x) + E^(9 x) + E^(10 x) *)
```

A less hacky but, IMO more dangerous way... unprotect `Power` and redefine to ensure `0^0` is whatever value it should be. There's a good answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60575/indeterminate-expression-00-encountered)