# Defining 0^0 to be 1

Tags: core-language

In a script, I need to define $0^0=1$ to simplify the writing of my functions.
I read this question : [Could I define 0^0 to be 1?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64179/could-i-define-00-to-be-1)

I don't understand the codes (I could copy/paste but I won't learn).

In the second answer he does this :

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0|0., 0|0.] = 1
Protect[Power]
```

I understand than Unprotect allows us to modify the definition of the function.

But what I don't understand is the vertical bar | : what does it mean ?

In fact I need to understand precisely the meaning of `Power[0|0., 0|0.] = 1`.

I know it defines $0^0=1$ but I don't understand the line.

Also, in the other answer, they use the symbol `/;`. What does it mean ??

Comment: See a section: [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478). Also, you can always hit F1 if you face something new.

Comment: @StarBucK `|` stands for `Alternative` which is kind of like an `Or` operation for definining `Patterns`