# Should I redefine 0^0

Tags: core-language, customization, arithmetic

I've found some times, while playing with combinatorics, that Mathematica can't calculate some functions because $0^0$ is not defined as $1$.

(I know that some people think that $0^0$ should be left undefined. I'm convinced that $0^0$ should be defined as $1$ and this question doesn't intend to open a discussion of that).

My question is this:

If I redefine $0^0$ as $1$ in Mathematica like this:

```
Unprotect[Power]
Power[0,0]=1
Protect[Power]
```

could I be breaking some internal algorithms of Mathematica?

I did redefined `FactorInteger[1]` as `{}` a while ago (and that help me to simplify many function definitions) and I haven't find any issues as a result of that, but I'm afraid that messing with Power could be more delicate.

Comment: This has come up before, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64179/9490) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60575/9490).  Mr. Wizard's solution in the second link seems like an elegant solution.  Any function you want to define, where `0^0` should be 1, define using ```Internel`InheritedBlock```, and the change will be localized.

Comment: `MichaelJacksonEatingPopcorn.gif`

Comment: "...could I be breaking some internal algorithms of Mathematica?" - Yes. Generally speaking, if you ever make a modification to something as basic as an arithmetic operation, anything that breaks afterwards is more than likely your fault. Why not reformulate your combinatorial formulae so that computing `0^0` is avoided? Otherwise, define a custom function like `myPower = If[#2 == 0, 1, #1^#2] &` and use that instead.