# Applying And to lists of Booleans

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, boolean-computation

I'd like to take `{True,True,False}` and `{True,False,False}` and apply `And` to get `{True,False,False}`. Right now I'm using

```
And @@ # & /@ Transpose[{{True, True, False}, {True, False, False}}]
```

Is that really the best way? I would like `And[{True, True, False}, {True, False, False}]` to work but it does not.

Comment: +1 Nice question, invites many possible responses.

Comment: Related: [(3217)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3217/121)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I like more :

```
MapThread[ And, {{True, True, False}, {True, False, False}}]
```

> ```
> {True, False, False}
> ```

**Edit**

We should test efficiency of various methods for a few different lists.

**Definitions**

```
Argento[l_] := (And @@ # & /@ Transpose[l]; // AbsoluteTiming // First)
Brett[l_]   := (And @@@ Transpose[l]; // AbsoluteTiming // First)
Artes[l_]   := (MapThread[And, l]; // AbsoluteTiming // First)
kguler[l_]  := (And[l[[1]], l[[2]]] // Thread; // AbsoluteTiming // First)
RM[l_]      := (Inner[And, l[[1]], l[[2]], List]; // AbsoluteTiming // First)
```

**Test I**

```
l1 = RandomChoice[{True, False}, {2, 10^5}];
Argento[l1]
Brett[l1]
Artes[l1]
kguler[l1]
RM[l1]
```

> ```
> 0.2710000
> 0.0820000
> 0.0530000
> 0.0520000
> 0.0390000
> ```

**Test II**

```
l2 = RandomChoice[{True, False}, {2, 7 10^5}];
Argento[l2]
Brett[l2]
Artes[l2]
kguler[l2]
RM[l2]
```

> ```
> 1.4690000
> 0.5820000
> 0.3840000
> 0.3700000
> 0.2890000
> ```

**Test III**

```
l3 = RandomChoice[{True, False}, {2, 3 10^6}];
Argento[l3]
Brett[l3]
Artes[l3]
kguler[l3]
RM[l3]
```

> ```
> 6.2320000
> 2.4750000
> 1.6530000
> 1.4150000
> 1.2150000
> ```

Comment: \o/ yay, good timings for me! :D Usually all the fast ones are posted before I get here

Comment: @R.M These posts appear to be a good promotion of `Inner`!

Comment: @Artes, just added another one to benchmark...

Answer (score 21):

I prefer using `Inner` for this, as conceptually, it is a generalized dot of the two Boolean lists with `And` as the operator.

```
Inner[And, {True, True, False}, {True, False, False}, List]
(* {True, False, False} *)
```

Comment: This might give the Wizard a conniption ;) : `{True, True, False} ~(Inner[And, ##, List] &)~ {True, False, False}`.

Comment: @J.M. You need to go deeper... `{True, True, 
  False} ~(And ~Sequence~ #1 ~Inner~ (#2 ~Sequence~ List) &)~ {True, False, 
  False}` **INFIXTION**

Comment: @R.M `True ~Sequence~ True ~List~ False ~(Null ~Function~ (And ~Sequence~ #1 ~Inner~ (#2 ~Sequence~ List)))~ (True ~Sequence~ False ~List~ False)
`

Comment: @OleksandrR. I once managed to really piss Mr.Wizard off by mocking him with `a ~Rule~ b` instead of the natural infix `a -> b` :)

Answer (score 17):

I like Artes' and kguler's answers, but I'd like to point out that in general

```
f @@ # & /@ list
```

can be more concisely written as

```
f @@@ list
```

For example:

```
And @@@ Transpose[{{True, True, False}, {True, False, False}}]

(* {True, False, False} *)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Thread`:

```
Thread[And[{True, True, False}, {True, False, False}]]
```

or, `Thread` with `Apply (@@)` :

```
Thread[And@@{{True, True, False}, {True, False, False}}]
(* {True, False, False} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party

```
BitAnd @@ Boole@l /. {1 -> True, 0 -> False}
```

Comment: Why not simply `BitAnd @@ Boole@l /. {1 -> True, 0 -> False}`? What does `Dispatch@` add?

Comment: @DavidCarraher it adds a tiny bit of extra speed that I didn't expect either with such a short simple list of rules. I'll edit it out anyway to favour cleanliness

Comment: +1 I thought about submitting `BitAnd@@Boole@l` myself but was disappointed that there was no short command to `unBoole` the outcome.  Perhaps `ReplaceAll` is the best way to `unBoole`.

Comment: @DavidCarraher, yeah, almost the same happened to me, disappointing, but I am more of a first post (then think/delete) person

Answer (score 4):

A silly one (convert both lists to numbers, multiply, convert back) and some timings:

```
(l1 /. {True -> 1, False -> 0}) (l2 /. {True -> 1, False -> 0}) /. {0 -> False, 1 -> True})

n = 1000000;
res = Table[
   l1 = RandomChoice[{True, False}, n];
   l2 = RandomChoice[{True, False}, n];
   {
    (r1 = And[l1, l2] // Thread) // AbsoluteTiming // First,
    (r2 = And @@@ Transpose[{l1, l2}]) // AbsoluteTiming // First,
    (r3 = MapThread[And, {l1, l2}]) // AbsoluteTiming // First,
    (r4 = Inner[And, l1, l2, List]) // AbsoluteTiming // First, 
    (r5 = (l1 /. {True -> 1, False -> 0}) (l2 /. {True -> 1, 
             False -> 0}) /. {0 -> False, 1 -> True}) // AbsoluteTiming // First
   }, {10}];

Mean /@ (res\[Transpose])
```

> {0.3687211, 0.6879394, 0.5338305, 0.3507201, 0.7428425}

`Inner` wins.

Comment: @artes Yeah, I beat you by two minutes though ;-) Anyway, it confirms that `Inner` is the winner.

Answer (score 4):

I want in on this fun.  Doesn't seem to be the fastest, but here it is:

```
l1={{True,True,False},{True,False,False}};
(# != 0) & /@ Times @@ Boole[l1];

(*{True,False,False}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

And in a late bid for the silver medal by subversive means:

`Unprotect@And; SetAttributes[And, {Flat, OneIdentity, Protected, Listable}];`

`l1 = RandomChoice[{True, False}, {2, 10^6}];`

```
Argento[l1]
Brett[l1]
Artes[l1]
kguler[l1]
RM[l1]
And @@ l1 // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.705648
>   0.288288
>   0.193292
>   0.163886
>   0.149485
>   0.160957

Comment: That this is very close in performance to kguler's suggestion is no coincidence: setting `Listable` on something that ordinarily would not be just calls `Thread` automatically. The 2ms difference is probably not significant. And please, use ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` or similar when resetting attributes on system functions!

Comment: @OleksandrR. Is there any documentation on InheritedBlock ?

Comment: Alexey has written it up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5686710), but there's no (public) official documentation that I know of. If you don't want to use undocumented functions, you can either use a `Listable` wrapper function, e.g. `Function[Null, And[##], {Flat, Listable}]` (though this is not very efficient), or just a normal `Block`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thank you a very useful link.