# Logical operations on a list

Tags: list-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Applying And to lists of Booleans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10211/applying-and-to-lists-of-booleans)

I have two lists filled with logicals:

```
demondata = {True, True, False, True}
numerdata = {True, False, True, True}
```

I would like to find which corresponding cells positions are both `True`. The only code I could come up with is:

```
toInclude = MapThread[And, {demondata, numerdata}];
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
demondata && numerdata
```

Not that there is something wrong with `MapThread`, it just seems more complicated than I thought it would be. In MATLAB, I can do:

```
list1 & list2  _or_  list1 > 10   etc ...
```

Comment: By the way... The word that goes with *numerator* is *denominator*. On the other hand, *Demonimator* sounds like an excellently cheesy sci-fi horror flick. :)

Comment: @artes I've a feeling that my answer may address this question , but is not a valid answer to the proposed duplicate ?

Answer (score 5):

You need use `MapThread` as

```
MapThread[And,{demondata,numerdata}]
(* {True, False, False, True} *)
```

Perhaps

```
 demondata && numerdata // Thread
```

is close enough?

And ... there is also:

```
Inner[And, demondata, numerdata, List]
```

Answer (score 4):

`MapThread` isn't *that* complicated but if you are looking for alternatives, two options spring to mind:

```
And @@@ Transpose[{demondata, numerdata}]
(* {True, False, False, True} *)
```

Or if you don't mind switching to 0s and 1s instead of logical values:

```
Boole[demondata]*Boole[numerdata]
(* {1, 0, 0, 1} *)
```

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something more fundamental.  I thought the same way you can add lists without map, you may be able to do logical operations on lists.

Answer (score 2):

This gives you the positions where both are `True`:

```
{demondata, numerdata}\[Transpose]~Position~{True, True}
```

> {{1}, {4}}

Comment: @rojo oops, yes you are right :) Fixed now, thank you.

Comment: Deleting the comment because you fixed it, +1