# Logical AND operation over several comparisons

Tags: list-manipulation

Let x and y be arrays defined as `Array[x, m], Array[y,n]` respectively.

How to generate the following function of $x$ and $y$ for variable $k$:

```
x[1]<y[n-k+1] && x[2]<y[n-k+2] && ... && x[k]<y[n]
```

Assume that $k<n$ and $k<m$.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10211/5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach, using `Table`:

```
n = 15;

doIt[k_ /; k < n] := And @@ Table[x[i] < y[n - k + i], {i, 1, k}]
```

Then:

```
doIt[5]
```

> ```
> x[1] < y[11] && x[2] < y[12] && x[3] < y[13] && x[4] < y[14] && x[5] < y[15]
> ```

Note: maybe you want to condition `k` on `m` as well

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in many ways. A good approach uses e.g. `MapThread`, taking e.g. $n = 7, m = 6$  :

```
And @@ MapThread[ Less, {Array[y, 7][[3 ;;]], Reverse[Array[x, 6]][[2 ;;]]}] //
TraditionalForm
```

> ```
> y(3) < x(5) && y(4) < x(4) && y(5) < x(3) && y(6) < x(2) && y(7) < x(1)
> ```

or `Inner` :

```
Inner[ Less, Array[y, 7][[3 ;;]], Reverse[Array[x, 6]][[2 ;;]], And]
```

**Edit**

As suggested in the comments let's add another general solution:

```
sol[k_, m_, n_] /; 1 <= k <= m <= n := 
    Inner[ Less, Take[ Array[y, n], {k, m}], 
                 Take[ Reverse @ Array[x, n], {k - 1, m - 1}], And]
```

so we have, e.g.

```
sol[4, 6, 7]
```

> ```
> y[4] < x[5] && y[5] < x[4] && y[6] < x[3]
> ```

Comment: I prefer the `Inner[]` version myself, though I personally prefer `Take[]` to `Part[]`+`Span[]`.

Comment: @J.M. With `Inner` there is no need to use `Apply` as in the case of `MapThread` and it seems to be faster.

Comment: Right, and the problem's structure just screams for `Inner[]` to be used. :)

Answer (score 4):

If

```
x = Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[10];
y = Symbol["y" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[6];
k=4;

And @@ Thread[x[[1 ;; k]] < y[[-k ;;]]]
(* x1 < y3 && x2 < y4 && x3 < y5 && x4 < y6 *)
```