# Map a function over the columns of an M x N array

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have a $N \times M$ list of lists, or rather, a list of records and I want to map a function over its columns (e.g. find the mean temperature, age, etc.). `Map` would apply the function to each list within the list, but I want to slice vertically, rather than horizontally. How can I do this?

Example: Return a list of means for `{{1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, { 3, 6, 9}}`
rather than `{1,2,3}`, etc.

The list:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, 
 {4, 5, 6},
 {7, 8, 9}}
```

Comment: Related: [(3217)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3217/121), [(10211)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10211/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Transpose` followed by mapping `Mean` over the array should do the job.

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
Mean /@ Transpose[data]
(* ==> {4, 5, 6} *)
```

Answer (score 16):

For `Mean` you don't have to do any transformation to the input array

```
 data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
 Mean[data]
 (* {4, 5, 6} *)
```

because  (from docs [Mean >> More Information](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mean.html))

[image]

that is, `Mean` "threads" over its input when it is fed an array.

In general, in addition to

```
func/@Transpose[data]
```

(as in @m_goldberg's answer)

you can also use

```
MapThread[func, data]
```

or

```
func /@ Thread[data]
```

to get

```
{func[{1, 4, 7}], func[{2, 5, 8}], func[{3, 6, 9}]}
```

Comment: Transpose is what I was looking for in the end. It let me map my KDE over my columns of data nicely.

Thank you very much kguler and m_goldberg!

Now I'm off to read up on memory usage...