# How can I check if elements between lists are equal?

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have two lists:

```
list1 = {a, b, c, d}  
list2 = {b, b, d, d}
```

And I want to get the output

```
{False, True, False, True}
```

(so testing when elements of list1 are equal to elements of list2)

How would I do this? I've searched for quite a while, but couldn't find any way to do this.

*Side info; this is for Project Euler question 4. I know how I want to solve it, it's just figuring out how to put it into *Mathematica* which is difficult to me.*

**SOLVED**
Using: MapThread[Equal,{list1,list2}]

Comment: If `a,b,c,d` are numbers, `Thread[list1 == list2]`.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ  This just gives me 'True' or 'False', not _{false,true,false,true}_ , which is what I'm trying to get

Comment: Duplicate of [26858](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26858/equating-two-lists-element-by-element)

Comment: @voidlife Thank you! I had read that thread a little too quick, only seeing the same 'Thread' option (not reading the 'MapThread' one.) Thanks again!