# How to apply # on different lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

If I have

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
list2 = {5, 6, 7, 8}
```

How can I do so, that

```
function[#1, #2]
```

takes `#1` from `list1` and `#2` from `list2`??

Comment: Duplicates: [(10211)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10211/121), 
[(15556)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15556/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MapThread[function[#1, #2] &, {list1, list2}]
```

Comment: No need for: `[#1, #2] &`

Comment: @David No, that's not the same, unless `function` happens to be listable.

Answer (score 9):

Since your question leaves a wide range of possible interpretations I suggest to examine these methods

```
Inner[ f, list1, list2, List]
```

> ```
> {f[1, 5], f[2, 6], f[3, 7], f[4, 8]}
> ```

or

```
f @@@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]
```

or

```
Thread[ f[ Transpose[{list1, list2}]]]
```

Perhaps you could prefer `Outer` providing all possible pairs

```
 Outer[ f, list1, list2]
```

> ```
> {{f[1, 5], f[1, 6], f[1, 7], f[1, 8]}, 
>  {f[2, 5], f[2, 6], f[2, 7], 2, 8]}, 
>  {f[3, 5], f[3, 6], f[3, 7], f[3, 8]}, 
>  {f[4, 5], f[4, 6], f[4, 7], f[4, 8]}}
> ```

or

```
f @@@ Tuples[{list1, list2}]
```

> ```
> { f[1, 5], f[1, 6], f[1, 7], f[1, 8], f[2, 5], f[2, 6], 
>   f[2, 7], f[2, 8], 3, 5], f[3, 6], f[3, 7], f[3, 8], 
>   f[4, 5], f[4, 6], f[4, 7], f[4, 8]}
> ```