# Map function over two lists

Tags: map

How to map a function over two lists, first one and than the other?

For example, assuming I have two lists {a,b,c} and {d,e,f}:

```
[#1 + #2] & /@ {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}
```

That maps the expression simultaneously, but I want a result looking like:

```
{{a+d},{a+e},{a+f},{b+d},{b+e},...}
```

Comment: `{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}} // Total`? p.s. `[#1 + #2] & /@` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate: [71988](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71988/5478)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) or [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) as follows:

```
Join @@ Outer[List @* Plus, {a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]
```

> {{a + d}, {a + e}, {a + f}, {b + d}, {b + e}, {b + f}, {c + d}, {c + e}, {c + f}}

```
Map[List @* Total] @ Tuples[ {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}]
```

> {{a + d}, {a + e}, {a + f}, {b + d}, {b + e}, {b + f}, {c + d}, {c + 
>         e}, {c + f}}

Also

```
List /@ Total /@ Tuples[ {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}] (* or *)
Tuples[foo[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]] /. foo -> List @* Plus
```

> {{a + d}, {a + e}, {a + f}, {b + d}, {b + e}, {b + f}, {c + d}, {c + 
>         e}, {c + f}}

Comment: Also can be written as `{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}} // Tuples // Map[Total /* List]`

Answer (score 4):

Try using `Distribute`:

```
Distribute[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}, List]
(*{{a, d}, {a, e}, {a, f}, {b, d}, {b, e}, {b, f}, {c, d}, {c, e}, {c,f}}*)
```

Comment: I actually want to get {{a+d},{a+e},{a+f},{b+d},{b+e},...}, not  {a + d, b + e, c + f} . So that the {a, b, c} list is mapped first, and then the other one.

Comment: Ups, sorry now I got it!

Answer (score 0):

As with other solutions, you have to do some cleaning up afterword, but you can use `Table` with lists defining the iterators:

```
Flatten[Table[{i + j}, {i, {a, b, c}}, {j, {d, e, f}}], 1]
```

If you really want to map it onto the lists, you can use the following, but the result is the same:

```
Flatten[Table[{i + j}, {i, #1}, {j, #2}], 1] & @@ {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}
```

either option outputs:

```
{{a + d}, {a + e}, {a + f}, {b + d}, {b + e}, {b + f}, {c + d}, {c + e}, {c + f}}
```