# Comparison Operation for Nested Matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a nested matrix `n` as bellow

```
n = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
a = {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}
b = {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 0, 0, th}, {0, 0, 1, sh}}
c = {{0, t, q, dh}, {1, 0, 1, th}, {0, 0, 0, sh}}
d = {{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}
```

[image]

containing letters and numbers. I am going to do a particular operation in each row yielding the result shown bellow:

[image]

> ```
>  {{{{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 0, 1, sh}}}, 
>   {{{0, t, q, dh}, {1, 1, 1, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}}}M
> ```

Comment: Please post code instead of images so we have something to work with.

Comment: Also, how exactly is this supposed to work? Are the differences always going to be simply nonzero vs zero?

Comment: in sub matrices in each row, and for corresponding elemenets in each of these sub matrices, the comparison between 0 and 0 is 0,  between 0 and 1, yields 1. and between 1 and 1 results 1.  and letters such as t, q, dh and so on must be repeated.

Comment: @Kuba, I am so sorry, I could not understand your question.

Comment: in 'n', as n = {{a, b}, {c, d}}, which is written above a11 must be comprised with b11, a12 (that is 't' will must be comprise just for b12 (that is same as a12), the correspoding elements: a12,b12.........a13,b13........a31,b31. and so on.

Comment: I know. But what if a12 is `1` and b12 is `bh`?

Comment: Actually the corresponded elements that contains letter are same. and will be repeated in the result matrix (m).

Comment: @Kuba, it will not be happen

Comment: Of course in my problem it does not happen your purpose.

Comment: @Kuba, why did I earn a -1 vote?

Comment: Please edit your comments above into the question. Without these the question does not make any sense at all as you are not specifying clearly what the operation is to involve, and nor does it actually ask a question.

Comment: Closely related: [(3217)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3217/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what would be a general pattern but for this case you can use:

```
{MapThread[Max, #, 2]} & /@ n
```

> ```
> {{
>    {{0, t, q, dh}, 
>     {0, 1, 0, th}, 
>     {1, 0, 1, sh}}},
>    {{{0, t, q, dh}, 
>     {1, 1, 1, th}, 
>     {1, 0, 0, sh}}}}
> ```

Alternatively:

```
List /@ MapThread[Max, n, 3] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & t & q & \text{dh} \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & \text{th} \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & \text{sh}
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & t & q & \text{dh} \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & \text{th} \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & \text{sh}
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Your result is :      {{{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 0, 1, sh}}, {{0, t, q, dh}, {1, 1,
    1, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}} ,while my desire is: {{{{0, t, q, dh}, {0, 1, 0, th}, {1, 0, 1, sh}}}, {{{0, t, q, dh}, {1,
     1, 1, th}, {1, 0, 0, sh}}}}

Comment: It can't as far as I know -- I don't think that is actually happening with these particular matrices. But you could use `Block[{Max},Unprotect@Max;Max[s_Symbol,0]:=s; ...`

Comment: @mfvonh It does not matter since there will not be a case of two different symbols. Or a case of symbol and `0`. That's why I've asked many questions before answering.

Comment: @Kuba Gotcha, I was just trying to clarify for mostafa , not to correct your answer :)

Comment: @mfvonh right, I probably should've explained that earlier so thanks :)

Comment: I independently arrived at almost exactly the same solution so I appended it to this answer.

Comment: @Kuba, No why?! I am practicing this one, again, for not forgetting which I have learn of you.

Comment: I am worried if other users who had tried to answer my question be unhappy if I accept just one answer while their answers are completely correct too.

Comment: @mostafa no, of course not, you should accept the answer that fits your need the best. which you are using or you just want :) Upvotes are indicators of correctness.

Comment: @mostafa take a look at [meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/920/how-do-you-reward-two-good-answers) there are couple of related topics. p.s. could you please delete old not relevant comments?

Comment: I deleted that were related to me. Ok I am going to take a look.

Answer (score 4):

If only `Max` were `Listable`:

```
listMax = Function[, Max[##], Listable];
```

Then:

```
List /@ listMax @@@ n // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & t & q & \text{dh} \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & \text{th} \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & \text{sh}
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & t & q & \text{dh} \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & \text{th} \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & \text{sh}
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \end{array}
> \right)$