# Transpose uneven lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a quick method to transpose uneven lists without conditionals?

With:

```
Drop[Table[q, {10}], #] & /@ Range[10]
```

Thus the first list would have the first element of all the lists, the 2nd list would have all the 2nd elements of all the lists, etc. If there are no elements, skips. I have a feeling that this should incorporate Mathematica's Reap / Sow function, but unfamiliar.

Comment: The version-8 tag should be used to indicate questions, issues or functions that are specific for version 8, and not to indicate which system you use yourself. Many tags have a 'tag wiki', a small explanatory text that describe their usage. Hover your mouse above the tag to see it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, but it is not trivial to comprehend. You would have to use the second argument of `Flatten` to implement a generalized transpose of uneven lists. For example:

```
(* Uneven list *)
list = Range ~Array~ 5
Out[1]= {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

(* Transpose the list *)
list ~Flatten~ {2}
Out[2]= {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5}}
```

For more information on how the second argument of `Flatten` works and what it can do, see [this answer by Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/5).

Comment: Damn, I wanted to write that. Anyway, I've asked what `Flatten`'s second argument does in a previous question and got a pretty nice answer, you can find it here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument

Comment: Wow `Flatten` is powerful

Comment: And the actor for Best Code Award goes to ......  Leonid! Thanks that is beautiful.

Answer (score 17):

Just to show that there are always a zillion ways to do things in Mathematica, here is my version. Actually, I myself would have used `Flatten` and its mind-shattering second argument after having learned of its existence a couple of months ago.

Contrary to the `Flatten` method this one is straightforward and easy to understand, but boorish and probably not very efficient.

I'll start with a slightly modified test table to better demonstrate the results:

```
t = Drop[Table[q[i, #], {i, 10}], #] & /@ Range[10]) // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The ragged array is changed to a rectangular using `PadRight`, padding it with a unique symbol generated by `Unique`. I then `Transpose` the matrix and remove the unique symbol by replacing it with `Sequence` (think of it as a black hole).

```
u = Unique[];
m = Length /@ t // Max;
Transpose[PadRight[#, m, u] & /@ t] /. u -> Sequence[] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

This is probably how Mr.Wizard does it:

```
Module[{u}, Transpose[PadRight[t, Automatic, u]] /. u -> Sequence[]]
```

Same result, but compacter code.

Comment: horrendous. +1 (for having the nerve to publicly display this)

Comment: @acl and proud of it ;)

Comment: I wrote the same thing years ago, but used `Module` instead of `Unique` and `Automatic` for `m`.

Comment: mr.wizard Should have thought of `Automatic` in `PadRight`

Comment: interesting.. spoonfeed the function. Never thought of this either! +1

Comment: Instead of the rigamarole with `Module[]`, one could use `Null` as the placeholder: `Transpose[PadRight[{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, Automatic, Null]] /. Null -> Sequence[]`.

Comment: This approach may be done (since v10.2) with `Activate@Transpose@PadRight[t, Automatic, Inactive[Nothing]]`.