# Reshape vectors exactly like in MATLAB

Tags: list-manipulation

This gives a 64×1 column vector in *Mathematica*:

```
F := Flatten[ArrayFlatten[
ArrayFlatten[
 Table[Subscript[f, i, j, k, l, m, 
  n], {i, 0, 1}, {l, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}, {m, 0, 1}, {k, 0, 1}, {n, 
   0, 1}]]]] // MatrixForm
```

as `F=(1:64)'` does in MATLAB.

In MATLAB, `reshape(F,16,4)` gives a 16×4 matrix, where *column* 1 is the first 16 elements of `F`, column 2 the 17th to 32nd, etc.

In *Mathematica*, the best equivalents for reshaping seem to be the top two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467961/how-to-reshape-matrices-in-mathematica).

But when I apply either of these commands, I do not get a 16×4 matrix that's constructed like `reshape` in MATLAB. Instead I get a 16×4 matrix where *row* 1 is the first four elements of F, etc.

I have tried adding transpose operations in every location imaginable, and still can't get my *Mathematica* output to match the MATLAB.
I've also tried wrapping `List[]` around the definition of `F` to make `F` appear like a row instead of a column, but everything I do seems to not work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: As dlimpid says, you just need a `Transpose` to the existing answer. Another related question that might be of interest: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/5

Comment: Just for interest as well to make the equivalent of `F=(1:64)'` in Mathematica you just do `Transpose[{Range[1,64]}]`. Also there is no reason to use `:=` (SetDelayed) in your example, you should use just `=` (Set) as nothing changes from call to call. Good luck!

Comment: That's because MATLAB stores matrix elements in column major order while Mathematica stores them in row major order.  "Reshaping" is reinterpreting the stored data without changing it, thus the storage scheme matters

Answer (score 15):

Just apply transpose to the top answer:

```
reshape[mtx_, n_, _] := Transpose[Partition[Flatten[mtx], n]];
```

Answer (score 7):

[ArrayReshape](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayReshape.html) (new in version 9) does just that.

Comment: One still has to `Transpose` the result to get the output desired in the OP.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Maybe, I don't have a Matlab copy to try it. My answer addresses the parts of the question dedicated to Mathematica reshaping tools.

Comment: @MatthiasOdisio `ArrayReshape` does the same operation as MATLAB's reshape (and thus it's an $O(1)$ operation).  The reason why the results still differ up to a transposition is that MATLAB stores matrices column-by-column while Mma stores them row-by-row.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, your comment is helpful (not like this one of mine!)

Answer (score 4):

You might also use the (undocumented) function `` Internal`Deflatten[] `` for the purpose:

```
reshape[arr_List, dims : {__Integer}] :=
   Transpose[Internal`Deflatten[Flatten[arr], Reverse[dims]]]

reshape[Range[16*4], {16, 4}]
   {{1, 17, 33, 49}, {2, 18, 34, 50}, {3, 19, 35, 51}, {4, 20, 36, 52},
    {5, 21, 37, 53}, {6, 22, 38, 54}, {7, 23, 39, 55}, {8, 24, 40, 56},
    {9, 25, 41, 57}, {10, 26, 42, 58}, {11, 27, 43, 59}, {12, 28, 44, 60},
    {13, 29, 45, 61}, {14, 30, 46, 62}, {15, 31, 47, 63}, {16, 32, 48, 64}}
```

Comment: (On the other hand, the new dimensions $p\times q$ should be commensurate with the old dimensions $m\times n$ (that is, $pq=mn$); otherwise, the function will crash the kernel.)

Answer (score 4):

Since `Deflatten` isn't in version 7 here is my proposal:

```
reshape[a_, d__] := Fold[Partition, a, Reverse@{d}] ~Flatten~ {1, 3}
```

Which could also be written:

```
reshape[a_, r___, p_] := reshape[a ~Partition~ p, r]

reshape[a_] := a ~Flatten~ {1, 3}
```

Test:

```
reshape[Range@24, 3, 8] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
reshape[Range@24, 3, 4, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
reshape[Range@24, 6, 2, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]