# Mathematica does not import .mat file correctly

Tags: export, import, matlab

I have .mat file that contains a binary (0,1) matrix with size 100*100*100.
I have used this syntax to import it in mathematica

```
binarymap=Import["matlab.mat","Data"]
Dimensions@binarymap(*Why the dimensions is not 100*100*100?*)
{1,100,100,100}

binarymap[[1,1,1,1]] == False (*Why false?*)
```

When I load it in Matlab, it works correctly. What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "why false?" You are the one doing the assignment, right? In any case, this is a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/5

Comment: @R.M., I see your comment but in Matlab when I display the matrix, it show 0 or 1!

Comment: @R.M., I don't see any duplication in my question and  any solution has been provided! thanks

Comment: Why this question is off-topic. It seems that you close randomly questions!

Answer (score 4):

*First of all I want to make it clear that Mathematica does import this file correctly.*

MAT files can contain multiple variables.  When importing a MAT file, Mathematica always returns a list of the values of these variables.  It appears that your MAT file contains a 3D array.  Thus Mathematica returns a list with a single element, that element being a 3D array.

If instead of the `"Data"` element you import the `"LabeledData"` or `"Labels"` elements, you will be able to see the variable names as well.

It also appears that your file contains an array of `logical` type (i.e. MATLAB's Boolean type).  Importing it gives an array of `True` and `False` values.  MATLAB displays "true" as `1`, but don't be mistaken: this is not a number, it is a truth value.  See here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html