# Importing data from a MATLAB file to MATHEMATICA

Tags: import, warning-messages, matlab

I have been trying to import some matrices from MATLAB to MATHEMATICA. The matrices are the output after I run the MATLAB file. I had saved that file in .MAT format and trying to import it in MATHEMATICA using "import" function but there is an error:

"Import::noelem: The Import element "P" is not present when importing as MAT

Set::wrsym: Symbol N is Protected

$Failed"

Maybe I am using the function wrongly, I typed:
N = Import["C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DDP\CODE\stiffness matrix\Shin_6.mat", "P"]
Here Shin_6 is the mat file, P is the matrix that I want from that file and I name that matrix N in my Mathematica file.

Please suggest me with some solution. Matlab version 2015b, Mathematica version 10.0

Comment: [`(MAT)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html). Also, consult the most common pitfalls Q&A thread.

Comment: `N` is also a protected term in Mathematica, because it is the [numerical evaluation function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html). I would recommend against single capital letter symbols, because many are protected such as `C`, `D`,`E`, `I` ...

Comment: Consider [MATLink](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/calling-matlab-from-mathematica/24478#24478).

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/how-to-get-matlab-data-imported-with-the-same-dimensions

Answer (score 8):

The syntax you use is wrong.  There is no import element called "P" for the [MAT format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html).  Take a look at the documentation: it lists the allowed elements: `"Elements"`, `"Rules"`, `"Options"`, `"Data"`, `"LabeledData"`, `"Comments"`, `"Labels"`.

You probably want `"LabeledData"`, so use

```
Import["file.mat", {"MAT", "LabeledData"}]
```

or alternatively

```
Import["file.mat", "LabeledData"]
```

which auto-detects the format based on the file extension.

The pick out the `P` variable from the output ([`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) or [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html))