# Multidimensional MATLAB conversion

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors, matlab

I try to convert this MATLAB code:
From:

- https://github.com/gpeyre/2013-SIIMS-ot-splitting/blob/master/code/toolbox/%40staggered/interp.m
- https://github.com/gpeyre/2013-SIIMS-ot-splitting/blob/master/code/toolbox/interp_adj.m

(useful to compute some prox of some functions):

```
case 3
    %% 3D field %%
    V          = cat(4, ...
                U.M{1}(1:end-1,:,:) + U.M{1}(2:end,:,:), ...
                U.M{2}(:,1:end-1,:) + U.M{2}(:,2:end,:), ...
                U.M{3}(:,:,1:end-1) + U.M{3}(:,:,2:end));
case 4
    %% 4D field %%
    V          = cat(5, ...
                U.M{1}(1:end-1,:,:,:) + U.M{1}(2:end,:,:,:), ...
                U.M{2}(:,1:end-1,:,:) + U.M{2}(:,2:end,:,:), ...
                U.M{3}(:,:,1:end-1,:) + U.M{3}(:,:,2:end,:),...
                U.M{4}(:,:,:,1:end-1) + U.M{4}(:,:,:,2:end));
```

"The dimension of U.M{1} is (N+1,N) while that of U.M{2} is (N,N+1) for 2D field".
I would like to have the same behavior on Mathematica, without a switch case, on arbitrary dimension.
I try to do some mix with Take, Drop, ... Without any success.

```
rank = 4;
size = 30;
baseDim = ConstantArray[size, rank];
U = Table[Array[Subscript[m, ##] &, ReplacePart[baseDim, k -> size + 1]], {k, 1, rank}];
```

The idea of the MATLAB code is to concatenate N sub-tensor by taking the begining of and the end of each dimension and sum them up.

Here the '4' stand for the dimension where I would like to catenate, that do the same job as "Join".
This is the intuition behind the Mathematica code above.
In pure Mathematica for a Tensor with Rank 4 above the special case code can look like:

```
Join[U[[1]][[2 ;; ,   ;; ,   ;; ,   ;;]] + U[[1]][[;; -2, ;;   , ;;   , ;;   ]],
     U[[2]][[  ;; , 2 ;; ,   ;; ,   ;;]] + U[[2]][[;;   , ;; -2, ;;   , ;;   ]],
     U[[3]][[  ;; ,   ;; , 2 ;; ,   ;;]] + U[[3]][[;;   , ;;   , ;; -2, ;;   ]],
     U[[4]][[  ;; ,   ;; ,   ;; , 2 ;;]] + U[[4]][[;;   , ;;   , ;;   , ;; -2]], 5]
```

[Edit]
The solution based on the answer of @Henrik-Schumacher:

```
With[{all = ConstantArray[All, rank]},
    Table[U[[k]][[Sequence @@ ReplacePart[all, k -> 2 ;;]]] + U[[k]][[Sequence @@ ReplacePart[all, k -> ;; -2]]], {k, 1, rank}]
]
```

Comment: Since most people here don't know Matlab, perhaps you could explain what the constructions do? For example, what are U, U.M, and what does "cat" do?

Comment: you're right I update the message, remove the irrelevant U.M and add more explanation.

Comment: In addition, a concrete MWE is appreciated.

Comment: The last Mathematica code is an example which is the working example, which I'd to generalize for arbitrary rank.

Comment: I am not convinced that the last code example returns what you want. Are you aware that you try to join arrays of different `Dimension`s?

Comment: @chkone Well, I mean a concrete tensor.

Comment: Since you're dealing with tensor, are you aware that the _Mathematica_ and _MATLAB_ represents tensor in different way?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/1871

Comment: Also, neither of your _Mathematica_ code sample works, please double-check it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yes, that is what Matlab code do too.

Comment: @xzczd that is for memory storage, in my understanding for tensor indexing seem the same m[[a, b, c, d]] will point out the same number in Matlab m(a,b,c,d).
This one work:
tmp = Array[Subscript[m, ##] &, {3, 3, 3, 3}];
Join[tmp[[2 ;; , ;; , ;; , ;;]] + tmp[[;; -2, ;; , ;; , ;;]], 
 tmp[[;; , 2 ;; , ;; , ;;]] + tmp[[;; , ;; -2, ;; , ;;]], 
 tmp[[;; , ;; , 2 ;; , ;;]] + tmp[[;; , ;; , ;; -2, ;;]], 
 tmp[[;; , ;; , ;; , 2 ;;]] + tmp[[;; , ;; , ;; , ;; -2]], 5]

Comment: The dimession give me:
Dimensions /@ {tmp[[2;;,;;,;;,;;]] + tmp[[;;-2,;;,;;,;;]],
  tmp[[;;,2;;,;;,;;]] + tmp[[;;,;;-2,;;,;;]],
  tmp[[;;,;;,2;;,;;]] + tmp[[;;,;;,;;-2,;;]],
  tmp[[;;,;;,;;,2;;]] + tmp[[;;,;;,;;,;;-2]]}
{{2, 3, 3, 3}, {3, 2, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 2}}
And the join:
Join[tmp[[2 ;;, ;; , ;; , ;;]] + tmp[[;; -2, ;; , ;; , ;;]],
  tmp[[;; , 2 ;;, ;; , ;;]] + tmp[[;; , ;; -2, ;; , ;;]],
  tmp[[;; , ;; , 2 ;;, ;;]] + tmp[[;; , ;; , ;; -2, ;;]],
  tmp[[;; , ;; , ;; , 2 ;;]] + tmp[[;; , ;; , ;; , ;; -2]], 
  5] // Dimensions
{3, 3, 3, 3}

Comment: Then your understanding is wrong, and your new sample is **not** working, please look at the output carefully, it contains terms like `4 Subscript[m, 1, 1, 1, 
  1] + Subscript[m, 1, 1, 1, 2] + Subscript[m, 1, 1, 2, 1] + Subscript[m, 1, 2, 1, 1] + Subscript[m, 2, 1, 1, 1]`, which indicates the output is not the one you expect.  This behavior can be simplified to the following: `Join[{A[x]}, {A[x]}, 2]`, and your  mistake will be even more obvious if you replace `tmp` with `tmp = RandomReal[1, {3, 3, 3, 3}];`.

Comment: BTW, in _v9.0.1_ the sample will cause `Join::headsd: Expression {A[x]} at position 1 is expected to have head List for all subexpressions through level 2.` warning, I'm not sure when the change happens though. I've posted a separate question about this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184208/1871). And, your _MATLAB_ sample doesn't seem to be correct, either. The following sample will cause `error: cat: dimension mismatch` warning and fail in _Octave 4.2.0_: `U=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];V= cat(3, U(1:end-1,:) + U(2:end,:), U(:,1:end-1,:) + U(:,2:end))`.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your post to mention where you got the MATLAB code from?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less sure it's from here:
https://github.com/gpeyre/2013-SIIMS-ot-splitting/blob/master/code/toolbox/%40staggered/interp.m
https://github.com/gpeyre/2013-SIIMS-ot-splitting/blob/master/code/toolbox/interp_adj.m

Comment: @xzczd indeed I didn't notice that.

Comment: -1 for posting the wrong _MATLAB_ sample and a wrong _Mathematica_ sample (the first one). You cannot simplify the `U.M{1}`, `U.M{2}`, etc. in the original code to a single `U`, Notice e.g. the dimension of `U.M{1}` is $(N+1, N)$ while that of `U.M{2}` is $(N, N+1)$ for 2D field. Please test your code first before posting it in the question.

Comment: @xzczd thanks for your feedback

Comment: Your samples still involve multiple mistakes. Once again, please test your code before posting it in the question.

Comment: I fix few typo issue, the code were tested. If you find something else let me know cheers.

Comment: 1. Some of the `U` isn't modified in the MATLAB sample. 2. You've chosen `rank=4` for the 2nd _Mathematica_ sample while in the 1st sample you've defined `rank=3`.

Comment: Thanks fixed. I didn't test the Matlab code. I work mainly on Mathematica.

Comment: Downvote retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to the final `Join` which I don't understand, the following might help:

```
r = 4;
tmp = Array[Subscript[m, ##] &, ConstantArray[3, r]];

With[{idx = ConstantArray[All, r]},
  Table[
   tmp[[Sequence @@ ReplacePart[idx, i -> 2 ;;]]] + 
    tmp[[Sequence @@ ReplacePart[idx, i -> ;; -2]]],
   {i, 1, r}]
  ]
```

or

```
Table[Map[2 MovingAverage[#, {1, 1}] &, tmp, {i - 1}], {i, 1, r}]
```

Comment: Dimension of both method give me {4} and not a tensor.

Comment: thanks that is the solution edit the original message

Comment: You're welcome.