# How to implement a Kalman or LQG regulator in the control of classical pendulum problem

Tags: control-systems

My final purpose is to realize an LQG control of inverted pendulum.

To this end, my first step I think is to build a Kalman regulator in Mathematica.
The original Matlab version of Kalman filter is written by Steve Brunton. I try to follow his code, but I am stuck when using the Mathematica command `KalmanEstimator` which complains “The number of columns in * is not equal to the length of * ”.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

My Mathematica code is below.

```
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;

m = 1;
M = 5;
L = 2;
g = -10;
d = 1;

s = -1; (* pendulum up: s=1 *)

(* y={x[t], x'[t], \[Theta][t], \[Theta]'[t]} *)
\[DoubleStruckCapitalA] = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0 , -d/M, -m g/M, 0}, {0, 0,0, 1}, {0, - ((s d )/(M L)), -((s (m + M) g)/(M L)), 0}};
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB] = {{0, 1/M, 0, s/(M L)}}\[Transpose];
\[DoubleStruckCapitalC] = {{1, 0, 0, 0}};
\[DoubleStruckCapitalD] = ConstantArray[0, {Dimensions[\[DoubleStruckCapitalC]][[1]], Dimensions[\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]][[2]]}];


(*Augment system with disturbances and noise*)
vd = 0.1  IdentityMatrix[4]; (* disturbance covariance *)
vn = 1 IdentityMatrix[1];(*disturbance covariance*)

(* augment inputs to include disturbance and noise *)
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]F = ArrayFlatten[{{\[DoubleStruckCapitalB], vd, 0 \[DoubleStruckCapitalB]}}]; 
sysC = StateSpaceModel[{\[DoubleStruckCapitalA], \[DoubleStruckCapitalB]F, \[DoubleStruckCapitalC], ArrayFlatten[{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, vn}}]},
SystemsModelLabels -> {{"u", "-", "-", "-", "disturbance", "noise"}, {"x"}, {"x", "dx", "\[Theta]", "d\[Theta]"}}]
sysFullOutput = StateSpaceModel[{\[DoubleStruckCapitalA], \[DoubleStruckCapitalB]F, IdentityMatrix[4], ConstantArray[0, {4, Dimensions[\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]F][[2]]}]}];

KalmanEstimator[{sysC, All, {1, 2, 3, 4(*dInputs*)}}, {vd, vn}]
```

Maybe the matlab code and its result is helpful, so I also pasted them here.

```
clear all, close all, clc
m = 1;
M = 5;
L = 2;
g = -10;
d = 1;
s = -1; % pendulum up (s=1)
% y = [x; dx; theta; dtheta];
A = [0 1 0 0;
    0 -d/M -m*g/M 0;
    0 0 0 1;
    0 -s*d/(M*L) -s*(m+M)*g/(M*L) 0];
B = [0; 1/M; 0; s*1/(M*L)];
C = [1 0 0 0];  
D = zeros(size(C,1),size(B,2));
%%  Augment system with disturbances and noise
Vd = .1*eye(4);  % disturbance covariance
Vn = 1;       % noise covariance
BF = [B Vd 0*B];  % augment inputs to include disturbance and noise
sysC = ss(A,BF,C,[0 0 0 0 0 Vn]);  % build big state space system... with single output
sysFullOutput = ss(A,BF,eye(4),zeros(4,size(BF,2)));  % system with full state output, disturbance, no noise
%%  Build Kalman filter
[L,P,E] = lqe(A,Vd,C,Vd,Vn);  % design Kalman filter
Kf = (lqr(A',C',Vd,Vn))';   % alternatively, possible to design using "LQR" code
sysKF = ss(A-L*C,[B L],eye(4),0*[B L]);  % Kalman filter estimator
%%  Estimate linearized system in "down" position (Gantry crane)
dt = .01;
t = dt:dt:50;
uDIST = randn(4,size(t,2));
uNOISE = randn(size(t));
u = 0*t;
u(100:120) = 100;     % impulse
u(1500:1520) = -100;  % impulse
uAUG = [u; Vd*Vd*uDIST; uNOISE];
[y,t] = lsim(sysC,uAUG,t);
[xtrue,t] = lsim(sysFullOutput,uAUG,t);
[x,t] = lsim(sysKF,[u; y'],t);
plot(t,xtrue,'-',t,x,'--','LineWidth',2)
figure
plot(t,y)
hold on
plot(t,xtrue(:,1),'r')
plot(t,x(:,1),'k--')
```

[image: matlab result]
[image: Mathematica Error]

**------------------------------- Updated post:-------------------------**

1. including a sinusoidal input
2. setting up an LQG based feedback control

**Updated questions:**

@Suba Thomas, thanks for your answer :)  It is really, really helpful. I still have some questions.

1. You seems delete the measurement noise from the input. Is it
   possible to include the stochastic measurements noise in the input
   (of system `sysC`), just like what Matlab did ?
2. With the help of your code, I try to include (1) a sinusoidal input
   and (2) to setup an LQG based feedback control. I updated my post to
   include the code for these two attempts. Am I doing correctly in
   these two efforts?
3. I am teaching myself some optimal control theory. However, I found
   that there are some confusing differences between contents of books
   and Mathematica. For example, few books mentioned descriptor
   state-space model, few books distinguish deterministic, feedback,
   stochastic inputs. Can you recommend a book that more close to
   Mathematica?

   Thanks.

**Updated code:**

```
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;

m = 1;
M = 5;
L = 2;
g = -10;
d = 1;
s = -1; \[DoubleStruckCapitalA] = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, -d/M, -m g/M, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, -((s d)/(M L)), -((s (m + M) g)/(M L)), 0}};
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB] = {{0, 1/M, 0, s/(M L)}}\[Transpose];
\[DoubleStruckCapitalC] = {{1, 0, 0, 0}};
\[DoubleStruckCapitalD] = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1}};
vd = 0.1 IdentityMatrix[4];
vn = 1 IdentityMatrix[1];

bs = {{1, 0, 0, 
    0}}\[Transpose];(* postion vector for the \
determinstic(sinusoidal) input (usin) *)
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]F = 
 ArrayFlatten[{{\[DoubleStruckCapitalB], vd, bs}}];

sysC = StateSpaceModel[{\[DoubleStruckCapitalA], \
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]F, \[DoubleStruckCapitalC], \
\[DoubleStruckCapitalD]}, 
   SystemsModelLabels -> {{"u", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", 
      "usin"}, {"x"}, {"x", "dx", "\[Theta]", "d\[Theta]"}}];

q = 10 IdentityMatrix[4]; r = 0.1 IdentityMatrix[1];
(* lqg regulator *)

lqg = LQGRegulator[{sysC, All, {1}, {6}}, {vd, vn}, {q, r}];

sscl = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[sysC, lqg, {1}, {1}];

y = OutputResponse[{sscl, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 
    50}];
Plot[y, {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Haven't looked into the code, but seems that you're trying to make a mechanical translation, then are you aware that MATLAB and Mathematica index array in different way?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/1871

Comment: Thanks for your attention. :) Yes, this is indeed a mechanical problem. I have noted the different ways that mathematica and matlab represents a matrix, and I don’t think this leads to the error in my code. It is more likely I used the KalmanEstimator command wrongly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system `sysC` needs to be modified as

```
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]F = ArrayFlatten[{{\[DoubleStruckCapitalB], vd}}];

sysC = StateSpaceModel[{\[DoubleStruckCapitalA], \
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]F, \[DoubleStruckCapitalC]}, 
  SystemsModelLabels -> {{"u", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"}, {"x"}, {"x", 
 "dx", "\[Theta]", "d\[Theta]"}}]
```

> [image]

Then the Kalman estimator can be constructed as

```
sysKF = SystemsModelExtract[KalmanEstimator[{sysC, All, 1}, {vd, vn}], All, -1]
```

> [image]

Trying to replicate the inputs used in the Matlab code.

```
range = Range[0, 50, 0.1];

impulseInput = 100 (UnitStep[t - 1] - UnitStep[t - 1.2] - 
   UnitStep[t - 20] + UnitStep[t - 20.22]);

processNoise = Table[Interpolation[
 Thread[{range, 
   RandomReal[
    NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[0.1]], {Length@range}]}]][t + 0.1], 4];

measurementNoise = Interpolation[
 Thread[{range, 
  RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {Length@range}]}]][t + 0.1];
```

The actual, true, or noisy outputs of the system.

```
xtrue = OutputResponse[sysFullOutput, Flatten@{impulseInput, processNoise}, {t, 0, 49}];
xtrue[[1]] += measurementNoise;
Plot[xtrue, {t, 0, 49}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Compute the filtered response and compare it to the actual.

```
OutputResponse[sysKF, Flatten@{impulseInput, xtrue[[1]]}, {t, 0, 49}];
Plot[{xtrue[[1]], %}, {t, 0, 49}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"Actual", "Filtered"}]
```

[image]

**Followup to the updated question**

For simulation, you can use `sysC`with the measurement noise included as in the Matlab code. However even the Matlab function `lqe` does not use that `sysC` for computing the gains. It is a rather wearisome design for these functions like `KalmanEstimator` etc to have a system with the matrices for the measurement noise included because it involves appending the system with zero matrices. Also, this noise is better characterized as noisy measurements and not as noisy inputs. With the latter, we have to distinguish between two kinds of noisy inputs - one affecting the process and the other the measurement.  As things stand, there are two options: a) Create `sysC`with the measurement noise included, and delete them when passing it to `KalmanEstimator` and avoid using `AddTo` during simulation. b) Create `sysC` without the measurement noise, compute the gains with `KalmanEstiamtor` and then use `AddTo` during simulation.

You need to use `SystemsModelFeedbackConnect`, and not `SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect`. Also it does not make sense to have $sin(t)$ as an input. It is a regulator and not tracker, and the natural reference input of the former is 0. If you want $x$ to track a reference $ x_{ref} $ add an additional state $x_i=\int(x_{ref}-x) dt$. Regulating that along with the others will try to drive $x$ to $x_{ref}$. If you are designing for a specific reference signal then you can try  [`AsymptoticOutputTracker`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticOutputTracker.html).

The function design is based on the standard control configuration [[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-infinity_methods_in_control_theory#Problem_formulation)]. The books on that page are all excellent ones. Descriptor systems are a bit different. Some of the equations we had to derive and make sure. But for the most part they are based on the book by Guang-Ren Duan [[Springer](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441963963)].

Comment: Thanks for your quick and great answer. I have several new questions on your code. For clarity, I think it’s better for me to update my post by adding my questions. Could you please take a look at it? Thanks :).

Comment: I have updated the answer in response to your followup questions.