# Create table A with entries of the form Ai_j

Tags: list-manipulation, import, matlab

I would like to create an $m \times n$-table `A` with entries `Ai_j`, where $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$. I have seen similar questions with subscripts, but I need the entries to be exactly of the form `Ai_j`, since I'm importing data from MatLab.

To be more specific, I have a list of equations with variables `Ai_j` from Matlab and I want to solve them with Mathematica. For this I need to specify for which variables to solve, but I'm to lazy to type them in one-for-one (its a huge matrix) so I just wanted to use `Flatten[A]`.

As written in the comments, another option would be to transport the matrix `A=sym('A',[m,n])` from Matlab to Mathematica, but I don't know how either.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need the entries to be exactly of the form Ai_j, since I'm importing data from MatLab"? Please be more specific. BTW, since you mentioned MATLAB, are you aware of this issue?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/1871

Comment: I have a list of equations with variables `Ai_j` from Matlab and I want to solve them with Mathematica. For this I need to specify for which variables to solve, but I'm to lazy to type them in one-for-one (its a huge matrix) so I just wanted to use Flatten[A]

Comment: …Well, if I understand correctly, you don't know `Part` (`[[]]`) can be used on multi-dimensional lists, too? If so, an example: `mat={{1,2},{4,5}}; mat[[2, 1]]`. Please check the document of `Part` for more info.

Comment: No, I give you an example. Given an equation `4*A3_5 +8*A7_9==0`, I would like to solve it for `{A3_5,A7_9}`. Now, I have a large number of much more complicated equations in variables `Ai_j`. So, how to effectively specify the list of variables in `Solve`?

Comment: Of course, another option is to transport the matrix `A=sym('A',[m,n])` from Matlab somehow to Mathematica (maybe this is what you meant), but I don't know how either

Comment: Is the equation system linear? If so, you can use `LinearSolve`.

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Do you mean you're importing symbolic expressions like `Ai_j` from MATLAB? If so, a more severe problem is, you cannot use `_` for variable naming in _Mathematica_, because it's the short form of  built-in function `Pattern`.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I wanted to do. And yes, this is a problem indeed

Comment: "…because it's the short form of built-in function `Pattern`" Oops, precisely speaking, it should be "`FullForm` of e.g. `Ai_j` is `Pattern[Ai, Blank[j]]`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the below code suffice?

```
{m, n} = {3, 5};
Array[Subscript[Symbol["A" <> ToString[#]], #2] &, {m, n}]
```

---

**Update**

Now that it has been figured out how to generate symbols without underscores in MATLAB, I provide a Wolfram version here:

`````
Array[Symbol[StringTemplate["A````"][##]] &, {m, n}]
`````

Comment: Unfortunately not, because of the subscript, but as xzczd pointed out in the comments of the OP, what I wanted doesn't work

Comment: @BipolarMinds Do you mean to let underscores (`_`) appear in the symbols?

Comment: yes, appareantly this is not allowed for variables

Comment: @BipolarMinds OK, it looks like you have learned about it. So I suggest you import those variables as `String`s and then delete (e.g., using `StringDelete`) the underscore characters before converting them into `Symbol`s, so that you will have `"Ai_j"` $ \rightarrow $ `"Aij"` $ \rightarrow $ `Aij`.

Comment: The problem is that I need to substitute the variables in the equations. So I think, it is easier to figure out how to create symbolic variables in Matlab without underscores. But thanks so far!

Comment: @BipolarMinds Ah, it turns out to be `A = sym('A%d%d', [3, 5])` in MATLAB.

Comment: THANK YOU!! You saved my day :)