# Using `GradientFilter[]` and `GradientOrientationFilter[]` to reproduce Matlab's `gradient()` function

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus, matlab

In ['gradient' function in MMA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249845/gradient-function-in-mma), two methods are given to reproduce Matlab's [`gradient()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) function. I thought that [`GradientFilter[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GradientFilter.html) and [`GradientOrientationFilter[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GradientOrientationFilter.html) could also be used, but half of the orientations are rotated by $\pi$ when I tried it:

```
grad[mat_] := Module[{gradPhi, gradMag, Sx, Sy},
  gradPhi = ImageData@GradientOrientationFilter[Image@mat, 2];
  gradMag = ImageData@GradientFilter[Image@mat, 2];
  {MapThread[#1*Cos[#2] &, {gradMag, gradPhi}, 2],
   MapThread[#1*Sin[#2] &, {gradMag, gradPhi}, 2]}
  ]
```

Tested with the example from that question:

```
y = x = Range[-2, 2, 0.2];
z = x Exp[-x^2 - #^2] & /@ y // Transpose;
pxy = grad[z];
ListContourPlot[z\[Transpose], PlotRange -> All, 
  ContourShading -> None, Contours -> 9, 
  ContourStyle -> ({Thickness[0.005], ColorData["Rainbow"]@#} &) /@ 
    Rescale@Array[# &, 10], InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
  DataRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]~Show~
 ListVectorPlot[Transpose[pxy, {3, 1, 2}], 
  DataRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

| This Attempt | Correct |
| --- | --- |
| [image: This method] | [image] |

Should this approach work, or am I confusing two different "kinds" of gradients/gradient functions?

Comment: According to the documentation, `GradientOrientationFilter` returns the angle of a vector *parallel* to the gradient, which means it may be off by $\pi$. In fact, the documentation states that the angle will be in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. (Side note: the filter functions should accept the matrices themselves, removing the need for the conversion to an image)

Comment: @LukasLang Hm right, I guess if it's parallel to the gradient, there's no way to know if the gradient is $+\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ off of that. That seems like a poor design decision...