# Is there a better way to add a "key" for the list of GatherBy?

Tags: list-manipulation

In ruby ,

```ruby
1.upto(10).to_a.group_by{|x| x%3}
```

gives

```
{1=>[1, 4, 7, 10], 2=>[2, 5, 8], 0=>[3, 6, 9]}
```

I would like use patten replace as a hash table in *Mathematica*. For example:

```
{1 -> {1, 4, 7, 10}, 2 -> {2, 5, 8}, 0 -> {3, 6, 9}}
```

I know I can use `GatherBy`, but it only contains the value. I tried to solve and I feel it isn't efficient for a large list.

```
fun = Mod[#, 3] &;
Thread[fun /@ #[[All, 1]] -> #] &@GatherBy[Range[10], fun]
```

Comment: I don't know why you don't like `GatherBy`... I would probably write the second line as `With[{fun = Mod[#, 3] &}, MapIndexed[fun@First@#2 -> # &, GatherBy[Range@10, fun]]]` On my machine, it does 10^7 integers in under a second.

Comment: So it seems not slow indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `MapIndexed`:

```
With[{fun = Mod[#, 3] &}, MapIndexed[fun@First@#2 -> # &, GatherBy[Range@10, fun]]]
(* {1 -> {1, 4, 7, 10}, 2 -> {2, 5, 8}, 0 -> {3, 6, 9}} *)
```

On my machine, this runs for $10^7$ integers in under a second, roughly on the same order as your own approach.

---

It can be made faster by noting that if you're using `Mod[#, n]&` as the function, your keys will be `Range[0, n-1]`. Hence, we don't really need to `Thread` or use `MapIndexed` when we can simply generate this list, do a [ragged transpose using `Flatten`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3644/5) and apply `Rule` at the very end:

```
Rule @@@ With[{n = 3}, 
    {RotateLeft@Range[0, n - 1], GatherBy[Range[10], Mod[#, n] &]} ~Flatten~ {2}
]
(* {1 -> {1, 4, 7, 10}, 2 -> {2, 5, 8}, 0 -> {3, 6, 9}} *)
```

Comment: Thinking about the nature of the problem itself vs. brute forcing it, always a +1 in my book.

Answer (score 7):

I would use [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) for this, or more specifically a re-packaging of them, originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4225830/198315):

```
SelectEquivalents[x_List,f_:Identity, g_:Identity, h_:(#2&)]:=
 Reap[Sow[g[#],{f[#]}]&/@x, _, h][[2]];
```

where the second argument is the (`f`) is the equivalence function, the third argument (`g`) transforms the data prior to being gathered, and the fourth argument (`h`) outputs the collection. Note, two arguments are passed to `h`, the first is the equivalence key and the second is the list of elements that match that key.

Then,

```
SelectEquivalents[Range@10, Mod[#,3]&, #&, #1 -> #2&]
(*{1 -> {1, 4, 7, 10}, 2 -> {2, 5, 8}, 0 -> {3, 6, 9}}*)
```

It should be noted, that this isn't a speed demon by any stretch of the imagination; clocking in at 24 secs on my machine, while [RM's suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15222/is-there-a-better-way-to-add-a-key-for-the-list-of-gatherby/15224#comment45017_15222) takes under a second.

Comment: +1 you really like 'SelectEquivalents[]', don't you? :)

Comment: @belisarius yes I do, and it moves it from the ToolBag.

Comment: While it isn't necessarily fast, it is _extremely_ flexible. Now we just need a packed form of `Reap` and `Sow`.

Comment: Good point, although not fast.

Comment: @chyanog no not fast. At issue, is that `Reap` and `Sow` unpack the array created by `Range`, and there is additional optimizations in `GatherBy` that even on unpacked arrays, it only runs 4 times as slow. Although, there may be autopacking involved in my one test ...

Comment: @belisarius Could you be so kind to explain what it means +1 since you haven't upvoted yet any answer today ???

Comment: @Artes I've upvoted this one, yes

Comment: @Artes I've watched this answer be upvoted and withdrawn at least twice, and downvoted and withdrawn once. So, it could be anything ...

Comment: perhaps I commented before upvoting ...

Comment: @belisarius I think you did, but it is only points. :)

Comment: How could you comment +1 and not upvote @belisarius, you work for Indec?

Comment: @Rojo I'm like the government. Always to blame, notwithstanding I do good or evil

Answer (score 4):

```
 fun = Mod[#, 3] &;
 selector = fun /@ Range[10];
 (# -> Pick[Range@10, selector, #]) & /@ DeleteDuplicates[selector]
 (* {1 -> {1, 4, 7, 10}, 2 -> {2, 5, 8}, 0 -> {3, 6, 9}}*)
```

More generally,

```
 ClearAll[pickEquivalents];
 pickEquivalents[domain_, fun_] :=  With[{selector = fun /@ domain},
  With[{range = DeleteDuplicates[selector]},
 (# -> Pick[domain, selector, #]) & /@  range]]
 pickEquivalents[Range[10], Mod[#, 4] &]
 (* {1 -> {1, 5, 9}, 2 -> {2, 6, 10}, 3 -> {3, 7}, 0 -> {4, 8}} *)
```

Comment: I always forget about `Pick`.

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* 10 introduced [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GroupBy.html) which does exactly what you want:

```
a = GroupBy[Range@10, Mod[#, 3] &]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {1, 4, 7, 10}, 2 -> {2, 5, 8}, 0 -> {3, 6, 9}|>
> ```

The result is an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html) which among other things can be [used for replacement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/121):

```
foo[2, bar[0, 1]] /. a
```

> ```
> foo[{2, 5, 8}, bar[{3, 6, 9}, {1, 4, 7, 10}]]
> ```

Also:

```
a[2]
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 8}
> ```

```
Lookup[a, {2, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 5, 8}, {1, 4, 7, 10}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
With[{fun = Mod[#, 3] &},
   Rule[fun[#1], {##}] & @@@ GatherBy[Range[10^6], fun]
   ]; // Timing
```

A neat way,but not fast.

```
GatherBy[Range[10^6], Mod[#, 3] &][[All, 1]] // Timing
(*{0.093, {1, 2, 3}}*)
#1 & @@@ GatherBy[Range[10^6], Mod[#, 3] &] // Timing
{0.234, {1, 2, 3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but I like it:

```
Reap[# ~Sow~ fun@# & ~Scan~ Range@10, _, Rule][[2]]
```

> ```
> {1 -> {1, 4, 7, 10}, 2 -> {2, 5, 8}, 0 -> {3, 6, 9}}
> ```