# Is there a faster way to Map an Association?

Tags: replacement, performance-tuning, associations

Consider mapping an existing `Association` in a manner such as this:

```
asc = AssociationThread[Range @ 26, CharacterRange["a", "z"]];

Map[asc, {{11, 13, 2}, {19, 23, 16}}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{"k", "m", "b"}, {"s", "w", "p"}}
> ```

Is there a more efficient way perform this generic operation?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why I would want to `Map` an `Association` like that when the natural thing to use here is `Replace` or `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: @RunnyKine You may already have an `Association` object to work with and converting to Rules and then Dispatch is slow (and pointless).  In fact my experimentation indicates `Association` is faster than `Dispatch in this application.

Comment: @RunnyKine I updated my answer to highlight the fact that use of `Association` is not included in the documentation for `Replace` that I can see.

Comment: Ah I see, I already knew they worked with `Association` objects, I thought I saw somewhere that almost all functions were updated to work with `Association`s so I just used them, didn't know this was not documented. Thanks.

Comment: I see you're shooting for the [Socratic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/146/socratic) badge ;)

Comment: @rm-rf What? Szabolcs beat me to it?!  NOOOO!!!! ;-)  Actually, unlike Legendary which I really did pursue I haven't thought about that badge.  One I am looking forward to is Generalist, but I just have to wait for that.

Comment: @RunnyKine I'm still getting my toes wet regarding Associations.  I just learned that `Lookup` can be faster still.  Do you know of any other method I can test?

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna suggest that but remembered I learned it from @rm-rf in this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41753/fastest-way-to-check-for-list-membership/41757#41757) way before the commercial release of **V10**

Comment: @RunnyKine I forgot about that answer. +1 on it now that I can run the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although [announced for 10.0.2](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) the functionality below works from 10.0.0 onward.

---

**Although apparently undocumented**  [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html) and [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) work with [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html) and this combination is considerably faster than `Map`.  Further it appears to be somewhat faster than using a [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html) table as well.

*Update: it seems [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Lookup.html) is faster still.  See additional timing result.*

#### Setup:

```
rules = Thread[Range @ 26 -> CharacterRange["a", "z"]];
asc   = <|rules|>;
d1    = Dispatch @ rules;
d2    = Dispatch @ asc;
```

Note another undocumented functionality: you can `Dispatch` an `Association`.

#### Test:

```
{{11, 13, 2}, {19, 23, 16}} /. asc

Replace[{{11, 13, 2}, {19, 23, 16}}, asc, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{"k", "m", "b"}, {"s", "w", "p"}}
>
> {{"k", "m", "b"}, {"s", "w", "p"}}
> ```

#### Timings:

```
time = Function[x, NumberForm[x // Timing // First // AbsoluteTiming, {4, 3}], HoldAll]

m = RandomInteger[{1, 26}, {2500, 2500}];

Map[asc, m, {2}]      // time
m /. asc              // time
Replace[m, asc, {2}]  // time
Replace[m, d1, {2}]   // time
Replace[m, d2, {2}]   // time

Lookup[asc, #] & /@ m // time
```

> ```
> {1.318, 1.248}
>
> {0.843, 0.827}
>
> {0.477, 0.468}
>
> {0.576, 0.562}
>
> {0.576, 0.562}
>
> {0.380, 0.359}
> ```

#### Notes:

1. `Replace` at *levelspec* `{2}` is almost three times faster than the equivalent `Map`
2. `ReplaceAll` is not as fast but still faster than `Map`
3. The origin of the `Dispatch` table appears to have no effect on performance
4. Although not included in the example relative timings hold with few or many rules