# Use map on a different level

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have just started to get used to Mathematica's Map, Apply, and related functions, and I can't figure out how to do maps that require working "one level down".

For example, I am currently trying to take a list of list of things, and basically perform a change of index.

```
index = {5, 3, 4, 1};
initial = {{1, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 1}};
(*goal: {{4,2},{1,3},{1,4}}*)
```

To get the new value, I just have to take the value from `initial`, and do `Position[index, #1]`.

The problem I have is that

```
Position[index, #1] & /@ initial
```

Means that `{1,3}` is passed as `#1`, which is not what I want. I could use `Flatten` to make the first part work, but I don't know how to "undo" the flatten to get back the original groupings.

Is there a way of dealing with these types of "expand list to elements" and the reverse operation when using `Map/Apply` or am I just trying to use the wrong tool for the job (in which case what is the right tool)?

**Alternative phrasing:** Is there a way to apply a function to some structure (`List`, `List` of `List`, etc) Mapping a function to all items with a `Head` different from `List` so that all the structure is preserved, but the values are changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is probably what you were looking for:

```
Map[Position[index, #][[1, 1]] &, initial, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{4, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}
> ```

Please see:

- [What do brackets around a levelspec option do?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121)
- [Levels: how do they work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121)

However you should avoid mapping `Position` whenever possible as it is highly inefficient.  See:

- [Why is there no PositionFunction in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/121)

If you are using *Mathematica* 10 you may use:

```
asc = First /@ PositionIndex[index]
```

> ```
> <|5 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 1 -> 4|>
> ```

```
Map[asc, initial, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{4, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}
> ```

This may also be done in one line:

```
Map[First /@ PositionIndex[index], initial, {2}]
```

Finally, following your **Alternative phrasing** I believe you want [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html)

```
foo = Function[x, asc @ x, Listable];

foo @ initial
```

> ```
> {{4, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Answer by @MrWizard,

```
initial /. First /@ PositionIndex[index]
```

also works.

Comment: Very elegant, though not as generalizeable

Comment: Very clean. +1 :-)

Comment: Of course you are correct.  The answer by @MrWizard is more general, but more alternatives often is better.  Besides, I am learning too.

Comment: Indeed, more alternatives = better.  I was remiss not to mention `Replace` as it tests faster as I noted in this self-Q&A: [(55980)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/121).  However I was focused on working up to the `Listable` example as I thought that most fully answered the question, and I forgot about alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

First, `Position` can work directly on more than one value but through `Alternatives`.

```
Flatten[Position[index, Alternatives @@ #]] & /@ initial
(*{{2, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}*)
```

but as you can see that `Position` starts with the first position found `{2,4}` which is not the way you want.

you can use `Map` to map the `Position` function on each elements in the list and then use the appropriate `Flatten` to get your result as follows:

```
Flatten[Map[Position[index, #] &, initial, {-1}], {1, 3, 4}]
(*{{4, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}*)
```

The meaning of that is `Map` will map the head `Position[index, #] &` to level {-1} which is the last level of the list which is basically the elements of the list (Check this `Level[initial,{-1}]`. So for example the first map will be:

`Position[index, #] &[1]` which will be `Position[index, 1]` which will be `{{4}}` and so on for the rest.

Another way is as you said to Flatten everything and then reconstruct the list structure using `Partition`

```
Partition[Flatten[Position[index, #] & /@ Flatten[initial]], 2]
(*{{4, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}*)
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining `Map[Position[index, #] &, initial, {-1}]` more? I don't get what the last argument to `Map` is doing

Comment: @soandos That is the *levelspec*.  Please see my answer and the links within it.