# Transpose a ragged triangular matrix and display as columns rather than rows

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, list-manipulation, display

I have a triangular list of lists as follows:

```
In[54]:= Tally[IntegerPartitions[#][[All,1]]][[All,2]]&/@Range[20]
Out[54]= {{1},{1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,2,1},{1,1,2,2,1},{1,1,2,3,3,1},{1,1,2,3,4,3,1},{1,1,2,3,5,5,4,1},{1,1,2,3,5,6,7,4,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,9,8,5,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,10,11,10,5,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,11,13,15,12,6,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,11,14,18,18,14,6,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,11,15,20,23,23,16,7,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,11,15,21,26,30,27,19,7,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,11,15,22,28,35,37,34,21,8,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,11,15,22,29,38,44,47,39,24,8,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,11,15,22,30,40,49,58,57,47,27,9,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,11,15,22,30,41,52,65,71,70,54,30,9,1},{1,1,2,3,5,7,11,15,22,30,42,54,70,82,90,84,64,33,10,1}}
```

I want to display each member of the list in a column (ideally with # as the column heading). I tried using *Column*, *Transpose* and *Inverse* to no avail.

Comment: With the output of the Tally called q, does `TableForm[q]` do what you wish?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for, provided the ragged array is named `ragged`?  `Table[ragged[[i ;;, i]], {i, 1, Length@Last@ragged}]`

Comment: It may be a duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3643/12)

Comment: TableForm results in each sublist being presented in a row, not a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simply transposing a ragged array, see [Transpose uneven lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/transpose-uneven-lists)

For displaying various transpositions both as upper or lower triangular formats, pad the array before display:

```
Transpose@PadRight[ragged, {Length[ragged], Length@Last[ragged]}, ""] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: I tried Flatten[Tally[IntegerPartitions[#][[All, 1]]][[All, 2]] & /@ Range[20] // Reverse, {2}] // TableForm and it almost worked (columns were reverse ordered). Is Ragged/Transpose better than Flatten?