# How to transpose unequal lists

Tags: list-manipulation

As the titel says I want to transpose a matrix containing rows of unequal length, to be able to transport them to excel (in row form, there are too many datapoint to write them in a cell. In another topic if found to use flatten : [Transpose uneven lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/transpose-uneven-lists)

However, this does not give me the right result:

Example:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4,5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
Flatten[list, {{2},{1}}]
```

Results into:

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {5, 5}}
```

But the result I want is:

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4,"" , "" , 4, 4}{,"" , "" , "" , "" , 5, 5}}
```

So I want to keep the rows together as they are, but only print them into columns. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the "rule" that puts the 4 in pairs front and back, yet the 5 is only at the back?

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you want?

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3},
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};

Transpose@PadRight[list, Automatic, ""]

{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
 {4, 4, "", "", 4, 4}, {"", "", "", "", 5, 5}}
```

Comment: your answer is most compact...always learning `Automatic`...got my vote despite nose in front in a  three horse race

Answer (score 4):

If the aim is for export into spreadsheet you could use:

```
With[{m = Max[Length /@ list]},Transpose@(PadRight[#, m, ""] & /@ list)]
```

Visualizing result to see if this is your aim:

[image]

Comment: And the photo finish.... @ubpdqn! Or so it showed up on my screen. :P

Comment: @MichaelE2 lol! now if only it answers OP's question

Comment: Great! All three results do what I want!

Answer (score 3):

```
maxLen = Max@(Length /@ list)

Transpose[PadRight[#, maxLen, ""] & /@ list]
```