# Plot a table of lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I want to make a point plot of a table with lists in it. Assume I have data like this:

```
data={{1,2,3,4},{5,6},{1,5},{2,4}};
```

and now I want to make a point plot which has points at the following places in the plot: (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,1), (3,5), (4,2) and (4,4).

Is there a quick way to do this, I couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `data = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}};
points = Flatten[MapIndexed[Transpose@{ConstantArray[First@#2, Length@#], #} &,data], 1];
ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red,PointSize[Large]]]`

Comment: its an ambiguous example. What would you expect if the first list was other than `{1,2,3,4}`  ( `== Range[Length@data]` ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will abuse the fact you want to plot points in specific positions, not get those coordinates:

If you know how to [transpose ragged array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3643/5478) it is quite strightforward:

```
ListPlot[Flatten[data, {2}], PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

as pointed out in comments, it is not general so here's something useful:

```
data = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {}, {1, 5}, {2, 4, 7}};

Join @@ MapThread[Thread[{##}] &, {Range@Length@data, data}] // ListPlot
```

[image]

Comment: how...how can this work~~I don't understand~~`Flatten[data, {2}]`gives `{{1, 5, 1, 2}, {2, 6, 5, 4}, {3}, {4}}`. how ListPlot handle such ragged list?

Comment: @Harry ListPlot by default puts values on x: 1,2... . And it will do this for every sublist in transposed array: {{1, 5, 1, 2}, {2, 6, 5, 4}, {3}, {4}}. If you remove `PlotStyle` you can see those sublists.

Comment: The only problem may appear if you receive list which matches: {{a,b}, {c,d}, ...}, then it may get this wrong and take explicit coordinates from those pairs.

Comment: I have another question, this doesnt work if my data list contains empty lists, for example data={{1,2},{},{3,4}}, it just skips these. Is it possible to include this?

Comment: will it work if the length of lists in the table increase? such as `data={{1,2,3,4},{5,6},{1,5},{2,4,7}}` ?

Comment: @Harry good point, thanks. Should work now.

Comment: seems that `Thread[{##}] &` is a useful code~~

Comment: @matti0006 You're welcome. :) Please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). It is good habit to hold on with an accept a day or two to not discourage other, you can always upvote answer you like anyway.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, makes more sense to have multiple answers as well!

Answer (score 4):

another approach:

```
data= {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}}
ListPlot[Flatten[
   MapIndexed[ 
     Sequence@{#2[[1]], #1} & ,data, {2} ], 1], PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 8}}]
```

[image]

more general example:

```
 data = {{2, 7, 8, 10}, {5}, {}, {0, 10}, {1, 7},
     {4, 9}, {0, 2, 4, 7}, {1}, {2}, {1, 8}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use `MapIndexed`:

```
data2 = MapIndexed[Thread@{First@#2, #1} &, data];
ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Automatic}]
```

[image]