# How to interleave data in a certain way

Tags: list-manipulation

Here's the deal: I have a table that has the form

```
 list = {{A,{a,b,c}},{B,{d,e,f}},{C,{g,h,i,j}}}
```

and so on, where the innermost lists can have an arbitary number of elements that differs from list to list, and I'd like it to look like

```
{{A,a},{A,b},{A,c},{B,d},{B,e},{B,f},{C,g},{C,h},{C,i},{C,j}}
```

and so on. How do I do this?

Comment: `Join @@ (Thread /@ list)`

Comment: My first answer was the following monstrosity: `Flatten[Inner[Outer[##] /. x_[y_] :> {x, y} &, 
  Sequence @@ Transpose[l], List], 1]`

Comment: @PatrickStevens How nice! :)

Comment: @belisariushassettled I am definitely of the "add more stuff until it works" school of programming.

Comment: related: [**85179**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85179/5478)

Comment: @PatrickStevens The Mathematica environment somehow encourages that. It is unbelievable how much one can entangle a simple problem by following a line of thought instead of giving it a break and think again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple one-liner:

```
Apply[Join]@*Map[Thread]@list

(* {{A, a}, {A, b}, {A, c}, {B, d}, {B, e}, {B, f}, {C, g}, {C, h}, {C, i}, {C, j}} *)
```

Comment: Love the mix of operator forms and composition.

Answer (score 9):

Since V10.0 you can use the following clear expression

```
Catenate[Thread /@ list]
(* {{A, a}, {A, b}, {A, c}, {B, d}, {B, e}, {B, f}, {C, g}, {C, h}, {C, 
  i}, {C, j}} *)
```

Comment: I checked that timings of `Catenate[...]` and `Faltten[...,1]` are almost the same.

Comment: +1 I always forget about `Catenate`!